# Mobile Device Detection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there an easy way to detect a mobile device and hide/show objects for different browsers. I'm duplicating pages for each browser and would like just to hide objects not needed.

Comment: maybe a dublicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Comment: Although this question is not specific to jQuery, [the accepted answer is for plain Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/322283).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code [found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755655/simplest-way-to-detect-if-mobile-device-with-javascript)

From there it would be a pretty simple process to implement what you need done.