# Javascript conditional with useragent variables

Tags: javascript, user-agent, conditional-statements

I need help writing a conditional with javascript for 2 videos. I have searched around but I guess I am confused about how to set my variables. I have 1 video (flash iframe) that I'd like to show on a desktop browser's site but I would like a different video (non-flash) to show when viewing the site on a mobile device.

These are the two videos:

```
<html>
    <div id="desktop_video">
        <iframe src="url-here" height="650" width="600" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"  marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="mobile_video">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://url-here"></script>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Say, you're trying to show the desktop at a minimum browser width of 480px, this would be your CSS:

```
#mobile_video {
    display: none;
}

#desktop_video {
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #desktop_video { display: none; }
    #mobile_video { display: block; }
}
```

Though the desktop should already be block, I added to code to be clear it's necessary. This is just a simple way to do this.

Comment: I like this method. However, it is not working for me on my iPad. The mobile video does not display and I am still receiving the Flash error message. Any insight?

Comment: I thought you had the rest set :) Try adding this to your header:                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
Also make sure you plug the size of your iPad there into the css max-width: 768px (I believe). Read here for more info: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Well now the iPad isn't calling in the desktop video, so not getting the Flash error which is good. But it still isn't calling in the mobile video, it's just blank. I'll have to come back to this in the morning. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Navigator.useragent` to detect client's browser. (There are a lot of resources out there if you search for it.)

I took the following line from [javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml) which will check if the user is using a mobile device...

```
//returns true if user is using one of the following mobile browsers
var ismobile=navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i)
```

You can display the mobile video (non-flash) if `ismobile` returns `true`. Or else you can just display the iframe video.

Hope this helps you to get a start. As I mentioned, there are lots of resources out there to help you with this solution, even on SO...

[How to detect a mobile device with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666907/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-with-javascript)