# Using tel: on mobile optimised and callto: on web

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to set a rule so that when my website is in desktop version it uses callto: for phone numbers and when it is in mobile optimised version it uses tel:
Any idea how to do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666907/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-with-javascript

Comment: @MittulChauhan if you flag a question for possible duplicate, it'll do all the formatting for you.

Comment: thanks a lot .. m new sorry.

Comment: It's technically not a duplicate. It's a good resource for his question, but someone may have specific insight on his problem.

Answer (score 2):

Skype now supports `tel:` links if that's why you are wanting to support `callto:` on the web.
If so, you should always use `tel:`.

Tested with Chrome, FireFox, & IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/CgRwV/