# A way to only use a CSS class on non mobile devices

Tags: html, css

So, I need a way to so that a CSS class is only used by desktops (Normal Screen).
Eg:

```
.class {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Is only used on desktops.

Comment: Check this entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666907/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-with-javascript there you could find the way in the answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it's not desktop specific, you can limit it to the screen based on the screen size with a media rule around it, like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .class {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

This would limit your rule to only be applied if the monitor was at least 640 pixels wide, larger than a smartphone (today, anyway).

Comment: this also works with js.
 var screenWidth = $( window ).width();

  
    if ( screenWidth < 800){your code}