# recognize whether a page is for pc or mobile device?

Tags: html, web-crawler, rd

I have a list of URLs and I am going to recognize if  the URL is for pc or mobile.
  the HTML page of the URLs have the certain mark for pc or mobile ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26577897/3585278

Comment: Do you have a definition of "a URL being for PC or mobile"? I don't know of an easy, clear or reliable way to separate these two.

Comment: @Danieboy I don't think this is about recognizing the client

Comment: @reto You might be correct about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a mobile device with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666907/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

There is no distinct way to recognize by certain URL whether website this URL pointing to is built for a mobile devices. There is no way even to recognize whether URL points to a website, it can be some resource, service, etc.

Some websites do not aware from type of the client, another have their own rules, for example, they can use subdomain like `http://m.domain.com/`. A large part of websites use [Responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design), having thus common content for any client type.

But there is no common rule or standard.

Comment: thx. It seems that I have to use serial strategies to handle that.