# When touching html button on iPhone, the href occasionally adds # to the URL: Why?

Tags: jquery, iphone, events, touch, touchstart

## [Here's a live demo page](http://jsbin.com/erumaz)

... and the relevant code:

```
$('#button').on('touchstart', 'a', function(e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
});
```

When using my iPhone4 and Safari 5.1.1, **sometimes** when touching the black button ([on my demo page](http://jsbin.com/erumaz)), I'll get a hash tag in the URL (i.e. http://foo.com/#). **It does not happen all the time**, only occasionally... It appears to happen when touching *slower* on the outside edge of the button.

I'm stumped!

Any idea what's going on here? Tips on how to make sure the link never fires?

---

#### EDIT #1:

I don't want the hash tag to ever appear in the URL. (sorry if this was not clear).*

---

#### EDIT #2:

For future readers: After asking my question, I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)... It's related to my issue and there's a ton of useful suggestions.

Thanks to everyone who replied here... If it was not for you, I probably would not have discovered the above thread.

Also, [here's my latest demo page](http://jsbin.com/inajiq/2) just in case anyone want's to see the solution I chose for handling "ghost clicks".

Comment: The `href="#"` set on the anchor tag is likely the problem.

Comment: I assumed the e.preventDefault() would handle that. Based on what Slaks says, I might need to put that in a click event also... Testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle and cancel the `click` event too.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about that! So, I should do something like: `on('touchstart click', 'a', function() { if (e.type === 'touchstart') { ...do stuff here... } e.preventDefault(); });`? Won't the click fire before the touchstart? Will the two conflict? Testing now and I'll be back with my findings. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a [new test page](http://jsbin.com/inajiq). That appears to help! **One of my concerns is that click and touchstart will both fire thus causing my code to execute twice.** But, on the iPhone, it appears as though it's one or the other, but not both. Interesting...

Comment: There's some [interesting comments over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)... Looks like I need to do some research on "Ghost Clicks".

Comment: I kinda like [this solution to handle "ghost clicks"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11507558/922323). I've [updated my demo page](http://jsbin.com/inajiq/2) to include that code.

Answer (score 0):

in order to add the href attribute to link elements but not have them go anywhere you can add "#" to the href.  : href="#" .  without it, the link loses the pointer cursor.

Comment: In this case, I don't want the href to go anywhere... I'm just curious as to why the e.preventDefault() is, from what I can tell, only partially working on Mobile Safari. Sorry if my original question was not clear. :(