# Prevent click on Ipad/Iphone when sliding a jquery slider

Tags: jquery, ipad, slider, touchstart, touchmove

I have structure

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have created sliding for iphone/ipad, I set the overflow:hidden on DIV and move UL up and down

The problem is that when I start touchstart event, by puting my finger on a link `<a></a>` and moving my finger up and down for slide, after sliding is done the location of the page is changed, the link click worked... I need to prevent that

I want to change the location of the page only and only when touchend is occured just after touchstart, no touchmove between them...

Give me advises please, Thank you

Comment: You might be interested on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've checked out the link, but unfortunately it doesn't not fix my issue

Comment: I only have touchstart event, which also is click when touchstarted on a <a> element

Answer (score 0):

```
inner_container.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
//e.preventDefault();
   .... 
});

inner_container.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  if(touch_moving){
    touch_moving = 0;
    return false;
  }
});

inner_container.bind('touchmove', function(e) {
  touch_moving = 1;
  ...
});
```

Notice that in touchstart default is not prevented !