# Attached the document.addEventListener on my element

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'd like to attach the event listener on my div tag so I know if the user tap the element. How can I achieve this with or without a jQuery.

```
<div class="chart" id="circle_chart">test</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        alert(event.touches.length);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#circle_chart").bind('touchstart', function(event) {...});
```

Should work **with** jQuery, see [How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both) for more on this and related issues.