# Is there in JQuery or JS event only for mouse click but not for touch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find event that will be fired on desktop click event (mouse or touch pad) but will not fire on mobile device with "touchstart" event. I need this because in this code

```js
$('#' + id).on("touchstart mousedown", function(event) {
    some actions
}
```

my actions will fire twice on mobile devices. First time on "touchstart" and after that on "mousedown". Now i'm hacking like that:

```js
var block = $(this);
if (event.type === "touchstart" && "mousedown" in $._data( block[0], "events" )) {
    $(block).off('mousedown');
}
```

But this is so ugly.

Is there any clear way to catch separate "touchstart" event on mobile device and something like "click" or "mousedown" that will fire only on desktop?

**UPDATE**. Hmm i think i found pretty answer on my question. I can detect 'ontouchstart' presence, determine device and bind events only after that. Thank for links!

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: check for `event.type`.. like `$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  alert( event.type ); // "click"
});`

Comment: @guradio You mean exactly like they're already doing?

Comment: Please, check answer in below link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522955/jquery-on-touchstart-mousedown-both-events-are-triggered-on-touchscreen-devi