# Best solution to replace mousedown in mobil devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

Am trying to find a way to minimize my ui with smartways of navigation on desktop and mobile devices.
What is the best solution to replace mousedown in mobil devices
http://codepen.io/shaikeomra/pen/XKNBVX

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(mouse_down) {
    //
    mouse_down = false;
    $("#header").animate({height: 46},300);
    $("#menu").removeClass("show");
    $(".pullmenu-icon").removeClass("hide");
    //
```

Answer (score 0):

vmousedown - this is from the jQuery Mobile documentation:

> "...allows the developer to register listeners for the basic mouse
>   events, such as mousedown, mousemove, mouseup, and click, and the
>   plugin will take care of registering the correct listeners behind the
>   scenes to invoke the listener at the fastest possible time for that
>   device."

https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/

EDIT: i would not replace the event handling, as modern devices can have both, a mouse attached and touch screen, but rather follow the hint described in this other SO answer:

[How to bind both Mousedown and Touchstart, but not respond to both? Android, JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655919/how-to-bind-both-mousedown-and-touchstart-but-not-respond-to-both-android-jqu)