# Why Javascript touchstart and mousedown events tiggered at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom-events

Take a look at this fiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanravi/tmeahm0d/2/)

I have attached two events to the div element first one is `mousedown` and second one is `touchstart`.

While clicking the element from the touch device both `mousedown` and `touchstart` is getting triggered, my expectation is only to trigger the respective events i.e only `touchstart needs to be triggered from the mobile device.

Comment: Why not just add one handler conditionally?

Comment: Mobile browsers trigger `mousedown` and `click`, too. You can assign the events to a variable. Use Modernizer.js for this.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655919/how-to-bind-both-mousedown-and-touchstart-but-not-respond-to-both-android-jqu) question for workaround if needed. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent) for details.

Comment: Touch devices will fire both the events https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#mouse-events

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qjqcerok/)

Normally the event order is : 
1) `touchstart`
2) `touchmove`
3) `touchend`
4) `mousemove`
5) `mousedown`
6) `mouseup`
7) `click`

When any of touch event gets cancelled, then mouse event won't be called.
Even if touch move occurs, then mouse event won't occur.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I tested Jasmin's solution, but it did not work for me, so I handled it via setTimeout

```js
let freezed = false;
let counter = 1;

const onPress = () => {
  if(freezed) return;

  freezed = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    freezed = false;
  }, 100);
  
  document.getElementById("counter").innerText = counter++
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("touchstart", onPress);
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("mousedown", onPress);
```

```html
<button id="button">
 Mouse down or touch me
</button>

<p>Counter: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
```