# HTML5 Puzzle function change

Tags: javascript, html

This is a jigsaw puzzle using HTML & js. I need to change the puzzle loading function. i.e. puzzles are creating only after clicking the image. Here I want to change this to load the puzzle when the HTML file is opened.

Tried: 'document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;' changed to 'document.onload = shufflePuzzle;' not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
const PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY = 4;
const PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT = '#009900';

        function init(){
            _img = new Image();
            _img.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);
            _img.src = "mke.jpg";
        }

        function onImage(e){
            _pieceWidth = Math.floor(_img.width / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
            _pieceHeight = Math.floor(_img.height / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
            _puzzleWidth = _pieceWidth * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
            _puzzleHeight = _pieceHeight * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
            setCanvas();
            initPuzzle();
        }

        function setCanvas(){
            _canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            _stage = _canvas.getContext('2d');
            _canvas.width = _puzzleWidth;
            _canvas.height = _puzzleHeight;
            _canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
        }

        function initPuzzle(){
            _pieces = [];
            _currentPiece = null;
            _currentDropPiece = null;
            _stage.drawImage(_img, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight);
            createTitle("Click to Start Puzzle");
            buildPieces();
        }

        function createTitle(msg){
            _stage.fillStyle = "#000000";
            _stage.globalAlpha = .4;
            _stage.fillRect(100,_puzzleHeight - 40,_puzzleWidth - 200,40);
            _stage.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
            _stage.globalAlpha = 1;
            _stage.textAlign = "center";
            _stage.textBaseline = "middle";
            _stage.font = "20px Arial";
            _stage.fillText(msg,_puzzleWidth / 2,_puzzleHeight - 20);
        }

        function buildPieces(){
            var i;
            var piece;
            var xPos = 0;
            var yPos = 0;
            for(i = 0;i < PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;i++){
                piece = {};
                piece.sx = xPos;
                piece.sy = yPos;
                _pieces.push(piece);
                xPos += _pieceWidth;
                if(xPos >= _puzzleWidth){
                    xPos = 0;
                    yPos += _pieceHeight;
                }
            }
            document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;
        }

        function shufflePuzzle(){
            _pieces = shuffleArray(_pieces);
            _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
            var i;
            var piece;
            var xPos = 0;
            var yPos = 0;
            for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
                piece = _pieces[i];
                piece.xPos = xPos;
                piece.yPos = yPos;
                _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
                _stage.strokeRect(xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
                xPos += _pieceWidth;
                if(xPos >= _puzzleWidth){
                    xPos = 0;
                    yPos += _pieceHeight;
                }
            }
            document.onmousedown = onPuzzleClick;
        }

        function shuffleArray(o){
            for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like its working fine, did you try alerting inside `init`

Comment: yes normally it's working, but I wan to change the puzzle loading. In this code first, it's showing the correct image, after a mouse click only its showing the puzzle. I need to show the puzzle directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;

It only shuffle your puzzle when your mouse down.
If you want to shuffle the puzzle onload without clicking, you need to call shufflePuzzle() directly.

I add _isWin variable to check winning condition, initialized with value false. If your user wins it will it to true. In buildPieces function, check _isWin, if it is false then it's the first render, shufflePuzzle();
if it is true, means user wins already, then remove frames and let user restart by clicking image

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>

        const PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY = 4;
        const PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT = '#009900';
        
        var _isWin = false;
        var _stage;
        var _canvas;

        var _img;
        var _pieces;
        var _puzzleWidth;
        var _puzzleHeight;
        var _pieceWidth;
        var _pieceHeight;
        var _currentPiece;
        var _currentDropPiece;  

        var _mouse;

        function init(){
            _img = new Image();
            _img.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);
            _img.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/1044787805533599/picture?type=large";

        }

        function onImage(e){
            _pieceWidth = Math.floor(_img.width / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
            _pieceHeight = Math.floor(_img.height / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
            _puzzleWidth = _pieceWidth * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
            _puzzleHeight = _pieceHeight * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
            setCanvas();
            initPuzzle();
        }
        function setCanvas(){
            _canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            _stage = _canvas.getContext('2d');
            _canvas.width = _puzzleWidth;
            _canvas.height = _puzzleHeight;
            _canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
        }
        function initPuzzle(){
            _pieces = [];
            _mouse = {x:0,y:0};
            _currentPiece = null;
            _currentDropPiece = null;
            _stage.drawImage(_img, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight);
            createTitle("Click to Start Puzzle");
            buildPieces();
        }
        function createTitle(msg){
            _stage.fillStyle = "#000000";
            _stage.globalAlpha = .4;
            _stage.fillRect(100,_puzzleHeight - 40,_puzzleWidth - 200,40);
            _stage.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
            _stage.globalAlpha = 1;
            _stage.textAlign = "center";
            _stage.textBaseline = "middle";
            _stage.font = "20px Arial";
            _stage.fillText(msg,_puzzleWidth / 2,_puzzleHeight - 20);
        }
        function buildPieces(){
            var i;
            var piece;
            var xPos = 0;
            var yPos = 0;
            for(i = 0;i < PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;i++){
                piece = {};
                piece.sx = xPos;
                piece.sy = yPos;
                _pieces.push(piece);
                xPos += _pieceWidth;
                if(xPos >= _puzzleWidth){
                    xPos = 0;
                    yPos += _pieceHeight;
                }
            }
            if(!_isWin)
              shufflePuzzle();
            else document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle
        }
        function shufflePuzzle(){
            _pieces = shuffleArray(_pieces);
            _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
            var i;
            var piece;
            var xPos = 0;
            var yPos = 0;
            for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
                piece = _pieces[i];
                piece.xPos = xPos;
                piece.yPos = yPos;
                _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
                _stage.strokeRect(xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
                xPos += _pieceWidth;
                if(xPos >= _puzzleWidth){
                    xPos = 0;
                    yPos += _pieceHeight;
                }
            }
            document.onmousedown = onPuzzleClick;
        }
        function onPuzzleClick(e){
            if(e.layerX || e.layerX == 0){
                _mouse.x = e.layerX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
                _mouse.y = e.layerY - _canvas.offsetTop;
            }
            else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0){
                _mouse.x = e.offsetX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
                _mouse.y = e.offsetY - _canvas.offsetTop;
            }
            _currentPiece = checkPieceClicked();
            if(_currentPiece != null){
                _stage.clearRect(_currentPiece.xPos,_currentPiece.yPos,_pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
                _stage.save();
                _stage.globalAlpha = .9;
                _stage.drawImage(_img, _currentPiece.sx, _currentPiece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
                _stage.restore();
                document.onmousemove = updatePuzzle;
                document.onmouseup = pieceDropped;
            }
        }
        function checkPieceClicked(){
            var i;
            var piece;
            for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
                piece = _pieces[i];
                if(_mouse.x < piece.xPos || _mouse.x > (piece.xPos + _pieceWidth) || _mouse.y < piece.yPos || _mouse.y > (piece.yPos + _pieceHeight)){
                    //PIECE NOT HIT
                }
                else{
                    return piece;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        function updatePuzzle(e){
            _currentDropPiece = null;
            if(e.layerX || e.layerX == 0){
                _mouse.x = e.layerX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
                _mouse.y = e.layerY - _canvas.offsetTop;
            }
            else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0){
                _mouse.x = e.offsetX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
                _mouse.y = e.offsetY - _canvas.offsetTop;
            }
            _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
            var i;
            var piece;
            for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
                piece = _pieces[i];
                if(piece == _currentPiece){
                    continue;
                }
                _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
                _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
                if(_currentDropPiece == null){
                    if(_mouse.x < piece.xPos || _mouse.x > (piece.xPos + _pieceWidth) || _mouse.y < piece.yPos || _mouse.y > (piece.yPos + _pieceHeight)){
                        //NOT OVER
                    }
                    else{
                        _currentDropPiece = piece;
                        _stage.save();
                        _stage.globalAlpha = .4;
                        _stage.fillStyle = PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT;
                        _stage.fillRect(_currentDropPiece.xPos,_currentDropPiece.yPos,_pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
                        _stage.restore();
                    }
                }
            }
            _stage.save();
            _stage.globalAlpha = .6;
            _stage.drawImage(_img, _currentPiece.sx, _currentPiece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
            _stage.restore();
            _stage.strokeRect( _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
        }
        function pieceDropped(e){
            document.onmousemove = null;
            document.onmouseup = null;
            if(_currentDropPiece != null){
                var tmp = {xPos:_currentPiece.xPos,yPos:_currentPiece.yPos};
                _currentPiece.xPos = _currentDropPiece.xPos;
                _currentPiece.yPos = _currentDropPiece.yPos;
                _currentDropPiece.xPos = tmp.xPos;
                _currentDropPiece.yPos = tmp.yPos;
            }
            resetPuzzleAndCheckWin();
        }
        function resetPuzzleAndCheckWin(){
            _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
            var gameWin = true;
            var i;
            var piece;
            for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
                piece = _pieces[i];
                _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
                _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
                if(piece.xPos != piece.sx || piece.yPos != piece.sy){
                    gameWin = false;
                }
            }
            if(gameWin){
                console.log('win')
                _isWin = true
                setTimeout(gameOver,10000);
            }
        }
        function gameOver(){
            
            document.onmousedown = null;
            document.onmousemove = null;
            document.onmouseup = null;
            initPuzzle();
        }
        function shuffleArray(o){
            for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... works like a charm... It solved my problem. Now facing another problem Its not showing the correct image after completing the puzzle. It's immediately changing to shuffle puzzle. Below I will upload the complete code.

Comment: I just updated the code. Please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Colin, one more request, how to add mobile touch facility in this code. As the puzzle swapping is not working in the mobile browser. Pls help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273142/would-onclick-event-work-on-touch-on-touch-screen-devices

Comment: Sorry Colin I could'nt make it workable, can you pls guide me?

Comment: Hi Colin, by mistake I made changes and tested the file locally, now I uploaded the files online server and now its working fine. Changes I have made:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32966255/7181834
2. http://touchpunch.furf.com/

now the touch works in mobile chrome browser.

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax for `onload` is incorrect:

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
  shufflePuzzle();
};
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: Sorry, I am not that much familiar on Js, please help me, where should I apply this code (inside a function or below?). I applied this code inside function init(), not working. Inside function buildPieces() by removing 'document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;'. Both are not working.