# Listening to mousedown AND touchstart on devices that use touch and a mouse (e.g. Surface)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, touch

So, I've run across an interesting problem while working on a Web application for the Microsoft Surface.

I want to add event listeners for when a user interacts with a DOM element. Now I can do:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  //Attach code for touch event listeners
  document.addEventListener("touchstart" myFunc, false);
} else {
  //Attach code for mouse event listeners
  document.addEventListener("mousedown" myFunc, false);
}
```

If the device didn't have a mouse input, this problem would be simple and the above code would work just fine. But the Surface (and many new Windows 8 computers) have BOTH a touch and mouse input. So the above code would only work when the user touched the device. The mouse event listeners would never be attached.

So then I thought, well, I could do this:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  //Attach code for touch event listeners
  document.addEventListener("touchstart" myFunc, false);
}
//Always attach code for mouse event listeners
document.addEventListener("mousedown" myFunc, false);
```

Devices that don't support touch wouldn't have the events attached, but a device that uses touch will register its handlers. The problem with this though is that `myFunc()` will be called twice on a touch device:

1. `myFunc()` will fire when "touchstart" is raised
2. Because touch browsers typically go through the cycle *touchstart* -> *touchmove* -> *touchend* -> *mousedown* -> *mousemove* -> *mouseup* -> *click*, `myFunc()` will be called again in "mousedown"

I've considered adding code to`myFunc()` such that it calls `e.preventDefault()` but this seems to also block *touchend* as well as *mousedown* / *mousemove* / *mouseup* on some browsers ([link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827)).

I hate doing useragent sniffers, but it seems as if touch browsers have variations in how touch events are implemented.

I must be missing something because it seems that surely these JavaScript implementations were decided with possibility of a browser supporting both a mouse and touch!

Comment: What does this have to do with Android, considering that the Surface does not run Android?

Comment: @CommonsWare - My question is pertinent to all touch devices that support a mouse as well, hence it seems applicable to Windows 8 and Android.

Comment: Yeah, what about chromeOS?

Comment: It's been 2 months. You figure anything out?

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of "How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?" which is a **jQuery**-specific question with jQuery-specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

For windows 8 you can use the "MSPointerDown " event.

```
 if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
     document.addEventListener("MSPointerDown" myFunc, false);
 }
```

Also add the following to your style:

```
  html { 
    -ms-touch-action: none; /* Direct all pointer events to JavaScript code. */
  }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557(v=vs.85).aspx for more info.

Comment: may disable scrolling

Answer (score -1):

Inside myFunc, check the event type. If it's touchstart, then do `e.stopPropagation()`.

```
function myFunc(e) {
    if (e.type === 'touchstart') {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    //the rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work either because it could be a "mousedown" event on a Windows 8 laptop which has both a mouse and a touch screen.

Comment: This breaks touch enabled devices from having click events.

Answer (score -3):

**EDITED:** 
If you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), you will be able to do like this:

```
var clickEventType=((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'mousedown':'touchstart');

$("a").bind(clickEventType, function() {
    //Do something
});
```

This will fire only one of the bind's event.

Found here: [How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It simply attaches handlers for both events and as such I don't believe it prevents the possibility of BOTH events firing (and hence the attached function firing twice).