# Changing my HTML5 game controls to mouse/touch

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

So I have my controls set up as space bar to jump but I want my HTML5 game to work everywhere so I need to change it to mouse/touch. Mouse/touch doesnt have a keycode so whats the most optimal way to do it for this code? Do I need to do mouse and touch separately?

```
if (KEY_STATUS.space && player.dy === 0 && !player.isJumping) {
  player.isJumping = true;
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
  jumpCounter = 12;
  assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
}

// jump higher if the space bar is continually pressed
if (KEY_STATUS.space && jumpCounter) {
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about touch events in JavaScript. You will have to add an event listener and catch if the user touches screen. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/) you can find a well documented tutorial in how to use it on both touchscreen and mouse.

Check out the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530734/handle-both-mouse-and-touch-events-on-touch-screens), you will have to do it like that. You will have to add an event listener on the `canvas` itself, like the guy did it on `myDiv`.

Here is an example I wrote (don't mind me being weird, please):

```
<div id="fakeCanvas">
    Click or touch me!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fakeCanvas = document.getElementById('fakeCanvas');

    function methodToInvokeForClick() {
        alert('I have been clicked!');
    }

    function methodToInvokeForTouch() {
        alert('I have been touched!');
    }

    fakeCanvas.addEventListener("click", methodToInvokeForClick, false);
    fakeCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", methodToInvokeForTouch, false);
</script>
```

I think you can take it over from now. What I did to the `fakeCanvas` `div`, you will have to do the same to your `canvas` by giving it an `id` etc. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have read the tutorial and it doesnt help with my problem I dont know how to incorporated into my game.

Comment: @GoogleFailedMe, I edited my answer. Check it out, it may help you out.

Comment: If I add an event listener on the canvas itself how do I use it in my if statement so I can get the player to jump? Can you edit my code so I can see how it would be done? thanks I am a beginner so sorry for not knowing

Comment: @GoogleFailedMe, oh by the way, I forgot to mention that I edited my answer again.