# .click doesnt work on touch devices although it works on browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

.click doesnt work on touch devices although it works on browser!

I am using a .click function that works fine on browsers, but when i try it on touchscreen devices, it won't work (the function isn't even called). The function should be called when i choose an select option. Is it possible that the problem is that the touch on an select option is not treated as a click? Is there a way to use the touch as a click in this specific situation?

```html
$brandImageOptions.find('.selecter-item').click(function(){
            //The console.log won't work with a touch, but will work with a click
   console.log("This event is happening LOL WUT Right? RIGHT?!");
   //DO STUFF 

  });
```

I also tried:

```html
$brandImageOptions.find('.selecter-item').on('click', function(){
            //The console.log won't work with a touch, but will work with a click
            console.log("This event is happening LOL WUT Right? RIGHT?!");
            //DO STUFF 

        });
```

and:

```html
$brandImageOptions.find('.selecter-item').on('click, touchstart', function(){
            //The console.log won't work with a touch, but will work with a click
            console.log("This event is happening LOL WUT Right? RIGHT?!");
            //DO STUFF 

        });
```

Thank for helping :)

The html is:

                                    MARCA

```
                                <div class="form-controls select-small">
                                    <select name="brands" id="brands" class="select">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="CHEVROLET">CHEVROLET</option>
                                        <option value="GMC">GMC</option>
                                        <option value="AC-DELCO">AC-DELCO</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

Comment: Here is a pretty similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530734/handle-both-mouse-and-touch-events-on-touch-screens

Comment: Have you tried using "touchend" event ?

Comment: I'm guessing $brandImageOptions is an array with selectors?

Comment: on click is working, so it does not matter if this is an array or not

Comment: Yes Donte, is an array with selectors.IDK How to use Touchend, any tutorial?

Comment: Exactly the same way as other events, http://jsfiddle.net/0qjdq7ez/

Comment: Thank You, will try it right now!

Comment: kuba, can you show me to use it in my case. I have no clues about what is the 'function' parameter on bind...

Comment: You can try something like that, but without full code, I'm not able to tell you for 100% that this will work ( http://jsfiddle.net/hm0y59w4/ ), you should also read more about binding events in jquery/ javascript ( e.g. here http://api.jquery.com/on/ )