# Prevent webview's simulated mousedown events in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, cordova

I'm trying to write a web application that can respond to both touch events and mouse events. Webview on android (and maybe other environments) trigger a mousedown event *and* a touchstart event when the phone is tapped. I'm running into a problem where the touchstart event triggers a page change, and the mousedown event is clicking a *different* button in the new page.

If its possible, the easy solution would be to force webview to *not* trigger mouse events alongside touch events (but only when an actual mouse is clicked).

I've read the answer here: [How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both) but it doesn't cover this case.

Anyone know how I can solve this problem in a general way?