# How to override on('click') to use touchend

Tags: jquery, click, touch

I'm working on a mobile app, however I have all the codes using on('click') event bindings.

I want to leave the code to use on('click'), however within that click even I want it to listen to touchend instead of click.

Is it possible? like extending or overriding this particular jquery function?

Comment: Are you using `jQuery Mobile` ?

Comment: no no jquery mobile >.<

Comment: Maybe you can use `"mousedown"` event.

Comment: `$(".selector").on("click touchend", function (e) { if(e.type == "click") { // do something } if(e.type == "touchend") { // do something } });`

Comment: This could perhaps help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both