# jquery html update working on computer but not on smartphone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, mobile

I'm using following-like code on my website

```
    <span class="box">
        <noscript>
        <a href="link.php"><img src="images/imagebox.png"></a>
        </noscript>
    </span>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('span.box').html('<img src="images/imagebox.png">');

        $(document).on('click','span.box', function(){

                   // rest of code

        });
    });
```

as you can see, i built it the way if the client has javascript, the content of  is replaced by  without  link so it's more interactiv for the client and if the client has no javascript, he still has  with the link the way he can still make the necessary action...

While this works perfectly without any trouble on the computer, on smartphone (at least mine), it doesn't work but i don't know why... actually, on my smartphone, i can't see the  and can't do any action as if it wouldn't have javascript while it has... I have android 2.1 on my smartphone...

Do you know any solution or workaround for this, the way i can have this  and necessary action ability even on smartphone?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: I finally opted for a solution like in [JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

All mobile devices don't handle click events.. should be:

```
$('<img />').attr('src', 'images/imagebox.png').appendTo('span.box').bind('click touchstart', function() {

   // handle click / touch

});
```

also see this post about double trgiggering issue in some touch enabled devices:
[How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)

Comment: problem is not the click but inserting the image... I've tried touchstart but nothing as the problem is coming before the click event...

Comment: edited my comment.. and in your example you don't have ending slash in img tag.. so it's not valid xhtml.

Comment: i m working with html5 so it's valid... it pass the W3C validator... but as said, image need to be inserted before click can be handled, in your example, you assume image is already visible while it's not, and that's the problem... :/

Comment: edited the answer.. now it adds image and binds events to it. Use your brains to change that code if not STILL suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

`$(document).on('pageinit', function(){});` or `$(document).on('mobileinit', function(){});` instead of

`$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: no, do not work any more nor on smartphone, nor on computer... :/

Comment: same as before, not working neither on computer nor on smartphone, even with jquery mobile... :s