# How to prevent "ghost" clicks on hyperlinks when tapping on touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit, touch

When I touch exactly on the border of an `a` tag element, it triggers a `click` event, but not a `touchstart` event. Why is this happening?

To show the problem I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8cvqL0L/8/
the `a` tag has 2 events:

```
$('#yellow').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    alert('touch');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#yellow').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('click');
});
```

Just make a touch exactly on the border of the yellow element.
Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

I tested this on Android Browser, Safari and Desktop Chrome.

Thank you very much!

**EDITED:**
The touch must be outside of the element but still within the radiusX/Y of the Touch to become a click.
The values of clientX/Y and pageX/Y in the `click` listener are not right, showing allways coordinates corresponding to the element when it´s not so. (http://jsfiddle.net/o8cvqL0L/35)

Having a container with `touchstart` listener seems making that these weird behaviour in the child element disappear, and the coordinates in the event object are right. (http://jsfiddle.net/o8cvqL0L/42/)
Then, using event delegation fixes the issue, BUT only when the target element is a `div` and not a link like in my previous example. Here the solution for `div` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/o8cvqL0L/44/

I´m still looking for a solution for `a` tags and a documented reason for these issue.

Comment: It seems also to happen touching slightly next to the element too.

Answer (score 1):

The touchstart event is actually fired in the code you provided.

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mssavai/o8cvqL0L/34/ I have modified your original code to display a border around `#yellow`. You'll see that touching the border area generates a touchstart.

However, touching near the edge will sometimes fire a click, which I think is the issue you are facing. From my observation (on Google chrome - android), this occurs if the touch begins outside the registered area, and then grows to cover part of that area when more pressure is exerted as part of the touch.

Comment: Hi! Yes, you´re right, it has to do with the touching area, but i have tested in chrome emulator and it´s enogh with the starting touch radius to fire the click

Comment: the question is: is this behaviour documented somewhere? and how can I prevent this from happening. I don't want a click to fire when tapping. I added some information to the question.

Answer (score -3):

Try this once, I think this will solve Ur problem.

```
$('#yellow').on('touchstart mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('touch');

});

$('#yellow').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```