# Responsive website: why would touchstart be needed instead of click?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, touch, touchstart

I'm developping a complex Single-Page-Application using ReactJS.

This page was initially a desktop browser application with lots of "onclick" listeners everywhere, including internal code, but also external plugins/libs that we can't modify easily.

But now we made it responsive, and it is available in both a mobile website and a Cordova/Phonegap app.

Just making the CSS responsive produces a nice result, without introducing `touchstart` event at all.

When the user touch an element with a click listener, the listener is called and the click event bubbles correctly ([except on iOS but it can be solved](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/mouse_event_bub.html))

So, unless I'm trying to implement touch specific complex features like drag&drop with touch, or special "synthetic events" like press, pinch, tap, swipe, (often provided by mobile-specific libraries), why would I need to use touchstart in any way?

For example I [often see people trying to mix both click and touchstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both) in applications according to the device capabilities.

But if `click` works, why would I need to care about `touchstart`?

What are the advantages of `touchstart` that are not handled by `click` already?

**Note:** this is NOT at all about the 300ms click delay which can be solved in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason we use touchstart/touchmove are for drag events, such as scrolling/inner-scolling detection.

For example, we want to detect the end of a scroll for infinite scroll.

On desktop we can use:

```
$('.whatever').scroll({ blahhhh
```

but on mobile we use:

```
$('.whatever').on('touchmove', blahhhh
```

Also you should definitely checkout [How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)

Comment: Thanks glad to know. By the way, the link you give me is already included in my question, and does not really answer it :)

Comment: @SebastienLorber haha I didn't even notice that! My bad!