# click and touchstart in ajax response on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, touchstart

i have a problem..
I have a `index.php` file which have a div inside with the result of an ajax request:

```
  <div id="content" style="margin-top:20px;" class="content_media"></div>
  <script>
        show_page('home');  HERE I CALL THE AJAX FUNCTION 
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
        var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        var eventType = isMobile ? "touchstart" : "click";
        $( "#content" ).on(eventType, ".escort_id", function() {
              alert(eventType);
              var id = $(this).attr("id");
              show_page('profilo',id);
        });
  });
  </script>
```

Alsways in `index.php` i call jquery, at the top of the page.
Then i have the response of the ajax request:

```
<div id="<?php echo $data['id'];?>" class="escort_id"></div>
```

The problem is that in mobile browser the "touchstart" event doesn't work, instead..on the desktop everything work perfectly..

[EDIT] 
Because i'm not a pro with javascript.. 
I made this script:

```
  var flag = false;
  $("#content").bind('touchstart click', ".escort_id", function(){
        if (!flag) {
              flag = true;
              setTimeout(function(){ flag = false; }, 100);
              var id = $(this).attr("id");
              show_page('profilo',id);
        }

       return false
  });
```

Because of the comment of mapek .. but what i have to put instead of `$(this).attr("id");`?

Comment: Could you please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7019461/3647441 - When binding both "touchstart" and "click" event you don't have to check for the user agent.

Comment: i've updated the post @mapek

Comment: i've tried it on mobile, it won't work.. on desktop the only problem is that the id posted is "content" and the page change as i want anyway, but on mobile nothing happen..