# jQuery bind to toggle opacity on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following JS which uses `fadeToggle()` which works fine however it does a `display:none` so the 3rd element which I always display jumps up so wondering if its possible to change to change the `opacity` to **`0`** so in theory the block is still there and nothing moves.

JS

```
$('.ty-banner__image-item.gt-banner').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
    $(this).find('div.image .banner-overlay').fadeToggle('fade');
    $(this).find('.content h2, .content p:first-child, .content p:eq(1)').fadeToggle();
});
```

Can I toggle to set `opacity` to  **`0`** on a toggle?

updated to use toggle class to add class fade which just changes `opacity: 0` but need to fade it some how.

```
// mobile touch rubbish
    $('.ty-banner__image-item.gt-banner').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).find('div.image .banner-overlay').toggleClass('fade');
        $(this).find('.content h2, .content p:not(".button")').toggleClass('fade');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right it sets `display:none` and the element space vanishes making the element after it takes its place, instead you need to use `opacity` with `animate()` function, just like this:

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nxa0p0Lo/3/)

```js
var toggleFlag = true;

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  
  // if the toggle flag is true, we set the opacity to 0, 
  // else we set it to 1, and animate the opacity property
  var op = (toggleFlag) ? 0 : 1;
  $('#second-div').stop().animate({'opacity': op}, 500);
  
  // finally we switch the toggle flag value to keep in control  
  toggleFlag = !toggleFlag;
});
```

```css
.divs {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#second-div {
  background-color: tomato;
}
#third-div {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first-div" class="divs"></div>
<div id="second-div" class="divs"></div>
<div id="third-div" class="divs"></div>
<button id="btn">animate</button>
```

---

Alternatively you can use `.css()` function with CSS transition like this:

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nxa0p0Lo/5/)

```
var toggleFlag = true;

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var op = (toggleFlag) ? 0 : 1;
  $('#second-div').css({'opacity': op, 'transition': 'opacity 0.5s'});
  toggleFlag = !toggleFlag;
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You need to bind it on either `touchstart` or `touchend` but not both because it'll response to both events and toggle its `opacity` too fast that the fade effect won't be noticeable.

[**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nxa0p0Lo/7/)

Comment: I have recoded it so it uses for mobile toggleClass which sets a class to change the opacity which works great and position stays but its just instant so need to fade that transition. ill have a look at your example above though as see if can adapt to animate it :)

Comment: its not onclick btw, the effect only happens on mobile devices when touchstart touchend..

Comment: ill update question now with what i have done... it just toggles class to add fade which does opaicty: 0 and back to opacity: 1

Comment: I know it is not on `click` this is just a deomsntration

Comment: with `toggleClass()` you wil lhave animation either on fade in or fade outyou need to use two CSS class and depending on the toggle flag value you remove the other and add the corresponding class

Comment: I think so, also use `on('tap')` too, give it a try

Comment: Yep i know i can add CSS to animate within the CSS and use: transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; but thought maybe a way in JS but think i might do like that lol

Comment: Would use tap but tap needs to action the click event as its a banner but know what you mean :)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both

Comment: I've just made this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/nxa0p0Lo/7/ and checked it with the devTool Device Emulator and it works fine, you need to either bind it to `touchstart` or `touchend` but *not both*

Comment: thanks mate for your help, i got it cracked but checked your example and although different yours done the trick as well so will mark as valid answer :)

Comment: always enjoy, shame live and breath it haha all week been starting 12pm and finished 9am (clients in australia heh, oh the joys lol)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is the behaviour of `fadeToggle` and you can't do much about it, but you can use an alternative method such as [fadeTo](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) which better fits your needs.

`fadeTo` only changes the opacity of an element, while the toggling part is something that you'll have to implement by yourself, but it shouldn't be complicated.