# My jQuery code is not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code which lets me hide submit buttons once users click on it (so that they don't click multiple times while the form is processing). It works perfectly on desktop and android, but doesn't work on iPhone. My jQuery knowledge is limited. Can someone please advise on how I can fix it?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#gform_next_button_5_85', this).on("click", function() {
    jQuery('#gform_next_button_5_85').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#gform_previous_button_5_85').css('display','none');
    jQuery('.pleasewait').css('display','block');
  });

  jQuery('#gform_submit_button_5', this).on("click", function() {
    jQuery('#gform_submit_button_5').css('display','none');
    jQuery('#gform_previous_button_5').css('display','none');
    jQuery('.pleasewait2').css('display','block');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: try read up on `touchstart` or `touchend`

Comment: check here [How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen will this work on desktop as well? or is touchstart and touched for mobile only?

Comment: @Shtarley you can combine `"click touchstart"`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you.... so will I basically replace  .on("click", function()
with
.on("click touchstart", function()
Or will I need to make more adjustments to my code?

Comment: @Shtarley check the link I provided above see how to use both

Comment: Thanks @MasivuyeCokile I am busy going through it, just a little confused as I have very limited JS knowledge.

Comment: click should work on mobile too, with delay but should work - it could be another issue here