# Clicking link image within does not log

Tags: jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

I have two links that have different structure.

```
<div id="content">    
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-uri="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
```

and

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-uri="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/084f45fb1ccb4bd208ad48dbffcd502f?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
 </a>
</div>
```

I have this function that should log data-uri by clicking `<a>` element.

```
var clickHandler = "click";

if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
    clickHandler = "touchstart";
}

$(document).on(clickHandler, '#content a', function() {
        href = $(this).data("uri");
        console.log(href);
});
```

For some reason link with image just does not work. Nothing get logged.

**PS. clickHandler variable is there adapt if page is viewed by mobile device that has touch feature.**

Comment: are you sure that onclick actually fired?
maybe all your links are not in a #content

Comment: I am sure since the first example is working. Both are inside #content. Let me edit the question content.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

delete this portion

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
 clickHandler = "touchstart";
}
```

and add this

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', 'a#content', function(event){
```

based on answer

[How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both#11507558)

Comment: This almost works. Now I am getting href from both links, but the one without image is firing twice. Each click on first example logs twice.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

You can go through this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PpXz5/4/

The code:

```
$("#content a").on("click", function() {
        href = $(this).data("uri");
        console.log(href);
});
```