# replace click with touchstart event for chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I have an angular app, inside it a unity 3d view that only react to touch events so on click it doesn't work but with chrome dev tool with touch enable it will work.

i need to make it accept clicking inside the document as a 'touchstart' event.
hope this make sense.

Comment: I think this could work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both

Comment: Hi Joseph thank you for your reply, it will not work because the unity script only interact with touchstart, i tested the code and didn't work.