# 2 event listeners, run function once

Tags: javascript

I have two event listeners, one for a Click and a Touch event. They both should run the same function, but only once. If they are both true on some devices it runs the function twice.

I want to be able to click a button and listen for two event listeners but only run the function once if either of them is triggered.

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    myFunction();
});
window.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    console.log("Clicked");
}
```

Comment: `touchstart` is not same as `click`.

Comment: @Rajesh yes, I need both of them listening but sometimes they overlap, both being triggered on some devices. I need to join them in case that happened so they only run the function once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019461/863110

Comment: You can use a global variable that will keep the state of the function being fired

Comment: What I meant was, `touchstart` is same as `mousedown`. A `click` combines/sums `mousedown`, `mousepress` and `mouseup`. So, you have 2 lifecycle events, so it will be called twice

Comment: Could function body be written in a way that function does not get called if it is already under execution?

Comment: @techie_28 — Since they execute sequentially and not in parallel: No.

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN's article on Supporting both TouchEvent and MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent)
:

> If the browser fires both touch and mouse events because of a single
>   user input, the browser must fire a touchstart before any mouse
>   events. Consequently, if an application does not want mouse events
>   fired on a specific touch target element, the element's touch event
>   handlers should call preventDefault() and no additional mouse events
>   will be dispatched.
>
> Here is a code snippet of the touchmove event handler calling
>   preventDefault().
>
> ```
> // touchmove handler
> function process_touchmove(ev) {
>   // Call preventDefault() to prevent any further handling
>   ev.preventDefault();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two events are fired almost simultaneously, you can prevent `myFunction` from executing twice within a pre-defined threshold using the following approach:

```
// threshold to reset allowing the execution
const _msThreshold = 200;

// date at which the function is last executed
let _myFnExecutedAt = new Date(0);

// your function
function myFunction() {
    console.log("Clicked");
}

// executer that checks if the threshold is exceeded
// to allow your function call and reset the timer
function execute() {
    if (new Date() - _myFnExecutedAt > _msThreshold) {
        myFunction();
        _myFnExecutedAt = new Date();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("click", execute);
window.addEventListener("touchstart", execute);
```

Bear in mind that you'll have to experiment a bit with the threshold value:

- If you set it too low, it might be exceeded before the second event registers so both will trigger.
- If you set it too high, subsequent real clicks/touches might not register.