# Use both mousedown and touchstart to change button content class and vice versa

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, vuejs3, touch-event

I have a button containing a child component which consists of a circle made with a div. I want the circle to change color when the user clicks with a mouse or touches the screen. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507558/11729954) and it kinda works but something is wrong because only the touchstart event is not causing the class to change.

I tried logging the value of `flag` in both the parent and child and even inspected the element manually to see if the class changed. The weird thing is, the values logged to the console are correct. When I touch-and-hold the button, `flag` is true and `color.value` is `green` but upon inspection (by pressing F12), Child component's class in the DOM is still `red`.

I tried using a different child component which is built from SVG and the same thing happens. The problem must be with the events. I learnt somewhere that `touchstart/touchend` events will be triggered first, followed by `mousedown/mouseup` then `click`. So I was thinking of just responding to `mousedown/mouseup`, to which the same problem is occuring.

I also tried commenting out the `// Suggested solutions` which worked for both mousedown and touchstart but for touchstart there was a delay between the color change and the button reacting(the native button press animation)

Can someone explain to me what is going on? And how I can enable the button to react and change its content's styles upon touch and click?

Would appreciate any comments or help. Thank you very much.

### My Button component

```js
<template>
<button class="slot-header slot-header-btn"
   ref="btn"
   @mousedown="cb"
   @mouseup="cbEnd"
>
        <Child :flag="pressed"/>
</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue"
import Child from './assets/Child.vue'

const pressed = ref<boolean>(false)

function cb(event: any) {
  // Suggested solution
  console.log("Mouse down")
  if(event.handled === false) return
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()
  event.handled = true

  // My own logic
  pressed.value = true
}
function cbEnd(event: any) {
  // Suggested solution
  console.log("Mouse up")
  if(event.handled === false) return
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()
  event.handled = true

  // My own logic
  pressed.value = false
}
</script>
```

### My Child component

```xml
<template>
  <div :class="`circle ${color}`">

  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, PropType, toRefs, watch } from 'vue';


const props = defineProps({
  flag: {
    type: Boolean as PropType<boolean>,
    required: false,
    default: () => false
  }
})


const { flag } = toRefs(props)

const color = computed<string>(() => flag.value ? "green" : "red")

watch(() => flag.value, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log(`Child color.value: ${color.value}`)
  console.log(`Child flag.value: ${newValue}`)
})

</script>

<style scoped>
.circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
</style>
```