# Touch screen detection: Chrome 17

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, touch

according to
[What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)
I implemented a touch device detection using

```
((!!('ontouchstart' in window) ? 1 : 0) == 1)
```

This statement nicely returns true or false, also in the newest Chrome Browser (v17); just as stated.
To beautify my code a bit, a put this statement into a small function

```
function isTouchDevice() {
 return ((!!('ontouchstart' in window) ? 1 : 0) == 1);
};
```

Unfortunately this function falsely returns TRUE on Chrome 17, whereas (as stateted above), the statement itself works correctly, if called inline or directly from console.

Others browsers (IE, FF) do not return wrong results.

Can anybody explain?

Comment: There's really no reason for that much redundancy in the boolean expression. All you need is `'ontouchstart' in window`. Now, as to why id doesn't work: I'd check [what Modernizr does](http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on Chrome 17 and I get false. (OS X 10.7.3)