# Any way to know if user has touchscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)

I want to apply a different styling to an element if the user is using a browser on a touchscreen device. Is there any way to know?

Comment: maybe this link will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript