# jQuery Lightbox Prev/Next buttons not displaying on iPad/iPod

Tags: jquery, html, ios, lightbox

I am designing a [website](http://www.aisforestry.com) and am using jQuery [lightbox 0.5](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

On the equipment pages I am using lightbox as a gallery. Everything works on a computer but on an iPad/iPod the Prev/Next buttons do not show up.

I know that it uses a jQuery routine to display them on `:mouseover` but there is no mouse on these devices. Tapping on the correct side of the button does work, but I'd like the buttons to be there too.

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.StockNumber').lightBox();
    });
</script>
```

Where `StockNumber` is the stocknumber of the unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the fixed navigation option:

```
$('a.StockNumber').lightBox({
    fixedNavigation: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I double checked the lightbox site and in the how to use and extended options and found no reference to this fixedNavigation option.

Would there be a way to only call this on an mobile device?

Comment: No problem. It is not on the options page, for some reason. I found it on the example tab. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript) to detect touch devices.