# Efficient ways to determine if client is using a touch enabled laptop/desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8, touch

With the number of new touch enabled full size PC's, what are some efficient ways to determine if the user is browsing with one of these touch enabled devices? Preferably a method that can detect any touch enabled device (Android, iPad, Windows RT, Windows 8)?

Comment: Check this out [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript), maybe it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using javascript, this is pretty widespread:

```
if('ontouchstart' in document) {
    // touch events detected
}
```

There are new touch devices coming out every week, so it’s probably safer to use the latest Modernizr if you want the best detection though.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following code in a previous project:

```
var is_touch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

if(is_touch){
    // Touch capable.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#touch) project has way of checking for touch capabilities but notes that there is not a completely reliable way to check as some desktop browsers lie about their support and some mobile browsers don't support the touch events.

Test results from a wide range of browsers are [here](http://www.browserscope.org/user/tests/table/agt1YS1wcm9maWxlcnINCxIEVGVzdBjGxLICDA).