# jquery preventing hover function on touch

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-hover

I have a hover function, if it's a touch device I'd like the hover event to NOT happen.  The problem is when you tap the link with a touch device it does the hover event before doing the click event, so you have to tap it twice for it to work.

this is the hover function:

```
$("#close").hover( 
    function () { 
        $("#close_2").css({
            display: "none"
        });
        $("#close_1").css({
            display: "block"
        });
    }, 
    function () {
        $("#close_1").css({
            display: "none"
        });
        $("#close_2").css({
            display: "block"
        });;
    }
);
```

and then I have this set up as the click function:

```
$('#close').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#full_image').animate({
        height: 0
    }, 300, function() {
        $('#full_image img').attr('src','#');
    });
    $("#close_1").css({
        display: "none"
    });
    $("#close_2").css({
        display: "none"
    });
    $("#close").css({
        display: "none"
    });
});
```

Comment: Try event.preventDefault() with hover. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: hmm how would you write that into it?

Comment: @Mihir That doesn't stop the method from executing, nor does it prevent the specified handlers from running. It prevents the *default* action, like the name suggests, which isn't the problem as described.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. Can you not detect if the device is a touch device? If it is then don't call the function.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

ended up using touch detection:

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);

if(agentID) { 
    $('#close').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#full_image').animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $('#full_image img').attr('src','#');
        });
        $("#close_1").css({
            display: "none"
        });
        $("#close_2").css({
            display: "none"
        });
        $("#close").css({
            display: "none"
        });
    });
}
else {
    $('#close').hover(
        function() {
            $("#close_2").css({
                display: "none"
            });
            $("#close_1").css({
                display: "block"
            });
        }, function() {
            $("#close_1").css({
                display: "none"
            });
            $("#close_2").css({
                display: "block"
            });
        }
    ); 
    $('#close').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#full_image').animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $('#full_image img').attr('src','#');
        });
        $("#close_1").css({
            display: "none"
        });
        $("#close_2").css({
            display: "none"
        });
        $("#close").css({
            display: "none"
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not touch detection. Is detection "if user is fan of apple". Why this is accepted answer?

Answer (score 15):

Make the .hover() method more explicit and combine it with .on():

```
var $close1 = $('#close_1'),
    $close2 = $('#close_2');

$('#close').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $close2.css({display:'none'});
        $close1.css({display:'block'});
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $close1.css({display:'none'});
        $close2.css({display:'block'});
    }
});
```

Then combine that with .off().

```
$('#close').on('touchstart',function(){
    $(this).off('mouseenter,mouseleave');
});
```

If you want the event to fire on click with touch devices, but on hover on desktop devices, then put the functions as a separate function you call within those actions respectively.

**EDIT**

Been a while since I did this answer, here is a better way:

```
$(function(){
    var isTouchDevice = ('ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window),
        $close = $('#close'),
        $close1 = $('#close_1'),
        $close2 = $('#close_2');

    if(!isTouchDevice){
        $close.on({
            mouseenter: function(){
                $close2.hide();
                $close1.show();
            },
            mouseleave: function(){
                $close1.hide();
                $close2.show();
            }
        });
    }

    $close.on('click',function(){
        $('#full_image').animate({height:0},300,function(){
            $(this).find('img').attr('src','#');
        });

        $close.hide();
        $close1.hide();
        $close2.hide();
    });
});
```

This doesn't require a "hover prevention" event to fire with each touch, basically sets capabilities on page load while not affecting the click event.

Comment: Specifying 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' specifically shouldn't make a difference, since `hover` is simply shorthand for that; the second method seems like it should work though. +1

Comment: hmm, so I added that little snipit in with the code I have posted above for hover and when I tap on the touch screen it still does the hover event first, then tap again and it does the click event.

Comment: @lifeinthegrey Here is where you can actually try spelling out the methods, the shorthand hover only works as a method now, the pseudoevent's use is deprecated so it doesn't work in 1.8+. `$('#close').off('mouseenter mouseleave');`. Just an idea.

Comment: ah damn i kind of suspected that but I had already changed it and didnt want to make it again haha ... code remodded

Answer (score 5):

I think a clear approach would be to:

1. Detect if the browser supports touch events
2. Add the hover event handler accordingly

If you're using something like Modernizr already:

```
if(!Modernizr.touch){
    // only if the browser doesn't support touch events,
    // add the hover handler here.
}
//add the click handler here, as you want it bound no matter what
```

See [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript) and [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript) for other options to detect touch capabilities.

Comment: this will totally work, but adds completely unnecessary overhead of bringing in a library.

Comment: ... which is exactly why I said "*If* you're using something like Modernizr *already*" and included the links to SO questions discussing alternate methods of detection :)

Answer (score 3):

On mobile side calling **preventDefault** in *touchstart* event prevents *mouseover*, *mouseenter*, *mousedown* and affiliated events. Detail: https://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/results/

```
    $('#close').on('touchstart',function(e){
        console.log('touchstart');
        e.preventDefault();
        //Do touch stuff
    });
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: This answer actually works (most answers here don't consider devices that have touchscreens + a mouse, like a touchscreen laptop), and is also the simplest answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because of Windows 8 and Ultrabooks, I expect to see a lot of devices that support both touch and pointer events.  As a result, I avoid disabling the hover event outright since it could potentially break the site for an touch enabled user with a mouse.

To solve this problem I ended up using two different classes for displaying menus, `.hover` and `.touch`, as well as separate events for hover and tap.

I'm using [jquery.finger](http://ngryman.sh/jquery.finger/) for capturing tap events, though any plug-in should work, this was just the smallest one.

*The HTML Would be something like:*

```
<li>
    <a>Some Link</a>
    <div>Some Content</div>
</li>
```

*The CSS would be something like:*

```
li div {display:none;}
li.hover div, li.touch div {display:block;}
```

*And the Javascript using JQuery:*

```
// Caching whatever elements I'm using for the navigation
a = $("a");
li = $("li");

// Set hover events
li.hover(

    // Both hover in and out fire whenever the user taps, aggravating!
    function(e) {
        // Close unused menus
        li.not(this).removeClass("hover").removeClass("touch");

        // Show this menu
        $(this).addClass( "hover" );
    }, function(e) {
        // Only closes if the menu doesn't have .touch, hell yeah!
        li.removeClass("hover");
    }

);

// Set the tap event
a.on('tap',function(e,data){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var thisParent = $(this.parentNode);

    // Close unused menus
    li.not(thisParent).removeClass("touch");

    // Toggle the current menu
    thisParent.toggleClass("touch");

    // The menu is open, so we don't need this class anymore
    li.removeClass("hover");
});

// Prevent the list items when being tapped from closing the drop down
li.on('tap',function(e){e.stopPropagation();});

// Close drop downs when tapping outside the menus
$(document).on('tap',function(e){
   li.removeClass("touch");
});
```

The important take away here is how I'm adding a seperate `.hover` or `.touch` class depending on the event, as well as removing the unused classes.  The order is important so the menus don't blink.