# How to handle touch events on devices that support both Touch and Pointer events with a menu with sub items that are not children of the parent menu

Tags: jquery, mobile, dotnetnuke, touch-event

I have an issue with **mouseleave** and **hover** on devices that supports both Pointer and Touch events. These devices include laptops with a mouse and touchscreen.

I basically just want to disable mouseleave and hover, but the problem is it is a device that supports both and I can't find an article explaining this properly and there are no standards.

I had a look at the following links:

[Disable hover effects on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291517/disable-hover-effects-on-mobile-browsers)

[How to remove/ignore :hover css style on touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885255/how-to-remove-ignore-hover-css-style-on-touch-devices)

[jquery preventing hover function on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388813/jquery-preventing-hover-function-on-touch)

[jQuery mouseleave for touch screen / tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882517/jquery-mouseleave-for-touch-screen-tablets)

[Disable hover effects on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291517/disable-hover-effects-on-mobile-browsers)

We are using DNN (DotNetNuke) as a Content Management system. I know that you can build custom menu's using tokens and DDR menu's, but this is too complex for what I want to achieve.

My simple approach was to build the sub-menu from data fetched from our ERP database and display it when you hover over a DNN page link which is "disabled" with a certain name that matches using jQuery.

Everything works fine on a Desktop Device. 
It also works with a Touch & Pointer device using Chrome.

I am having an issue with Edge on a Tablet Device with Touch and Pointer events. The onmouseleave is fired when you tap on "Categories" which will cause the sub-menu to close. When you tap on the "Categories" menu, it fires the hover event.

What makes it more difficult is that the Sub-menu is not a direct child of the parent, so it is not always easy to use CSS selectors. Currently I place the module beneath the menu so that it is at least very close so that I can use Absolute and Relative positioning to get the sub-menu to display directly below the links. This is where you will notice that I have added a timeout function on the one mouseleave event to allow someone to navigate to the sub-menu when their mouse leaves the hover event.

Here is a screenshot of the menu. It contains sub categories which can show, but I just want to get the main menu showing properly on devices with both Touch and Point event support.

[image]

**Example JSFidle Code**

**JSFidle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Tig7r/e6k9cfj1/13/

**HTML**

```
<nav class="NavMenu">
  <ul class="ul_menu">
  <li class='item'><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class='item'><a><span>Categories</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="subLevel MegaMenuDiv" id="MegaMenuDiv">
  <div class="custom_megamenu_wrapper">
   <ul class="main-category-list has-children"><li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Parent_Mega_Menu_Categories MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren" style="">Accessories</a>
      <ul class="secondary-items">
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com" class="MegaMenu_Child_Link" style="">Accessory Holders</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com" class="MegaMenu_Child_Link" style="">Whiteboard Starter Pack</a></li>
   </ul></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.NavMenu{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white !important;
}

.NavMenu ul li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}

.ul_menu li a:link{
  color:white;
}

.ul_menu li a:hover{
  color:black;
}

#MegaMenuDiv{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  width:550px;
  display:none;
  min-height:300px;
}

.MegaMenuDiv a:link{
  color:white;
}

.displayHiddenMenu{
  display: block !important;
}

.main-category-list li{
  list-style:none;
}

.secondary-items{
  background: #31383e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
  width: calc(80vw - 50%);
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  display: none;
  height: 92%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-width: 840px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.secondary-items a:link, .secondary-items a:visited{
  color:white !important;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".item:contains(Categories)").hover(function () {
        if ($('.MegaMenuDiv').hasClass('displayHiddenMenu')) {          
        } else {
            console.log('No class, adding class');
            $('.MegaMenuDiv').addClass("displayHiddenMenu");
        }
    }); 

 /* Removes the submenu when the mouse moves away from categories */
 $('.item:contains(Categories)').on("mouseleave", function (event) {
       if ($('.MegaMenuDiv:hover').length > 0) {
       // do nothing
       } else {             
                $('.MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
       }
});

$(".item:contains(Categories)").hover(function () {
    if ($('.MegaMenuDiv').hasClass('displayHiddenMenu')) {
      console.log('Item has class');
    } else {
      console.log('No class, adding class');
      $('.MegaMenuDiv').addClass("displayHiddenMenu");
    }
});

  $(".item:contains(Categories)").on("touchstart click", function () {
    if ($('.MegaMenuDiv').hasClass('displayHiddenMenu')) {
      $('.MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
    } else {
      $('.MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
      $('.MegaMenuDiv').addClass("displayHiddenMenu");
    }
  });

  $('.MegaMenuDiv').on("mouseleave", function () {
    console.log('Mouseleave remove class');
    $('.MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
  });

//Code for child menu elements
  $('.MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren').hover(function () {
        if ($(this).next().hasClass('displayHiddenMenu')) {
                //do nothing
        } else {
            $('.MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren').next().removeClass('displayHiddenMenu');
            $(this).next().addClass('displayHiddenMenu');
        }
});

$('.MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren').on('touchstart click', function () {
        var secondaryitems = $(this).next();        
        if ($(secondaryitems).hasClass('displayHiddenMenu')) {

        } else {
            $('.MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren').next().not(secondaryitems).removeClass('displayHiddenMenu');
            $(secondaryitems).addClass("displayHiddenMenu");
        }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played around with some of the code and managed to get it to work.
The **mouseleave** and **hover** event wont be fired on Touch Devices which makes it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var touched = false;

    $(".item:contains(Categories)").on("mouseenter click", function (e) {
        if (!touched) {
            e.type == 'click' ? $('.MegaMenuDiv').toggleClass("displayHiddenMenu") : $('.MegaMenuDiv').addClass("displayHiddenMenu");
        }
    }).on('touchstart', function (e) {
        touched = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            touched = false;
        }, 300);
        // do touchstart stuff (similar to click or not)
        // toggle MegaMenuDiv on click
        if ($('.MegaMenuDiv').hasClass('displayHiddenMenu')) {
            $('.MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
        } else {
            $('.MegaMenuDiv').addClass("displayHiddenMenu");
        }
    });

    $('.MegaMenuDiv').on("mouseleave", function () {
        if (!touched) {
            $('.MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
        }
    });

    // MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren - Show children items
    $(".MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren").on('mouseenter touchstart click', function () {
        // toggle MegaMenuDiv
        $('.MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren').next().removeClass('displayHiddenMenu');
        $(this).next().addClass('displayHiddenMenu');
    });

    //Removes the sub-menu when hovering over other menu items
    $('.item').not(".item:contains(Categories)").hover(function () {
        console.log('Hovering over other items, remove class');
        if ($('.MegaMenuDiv').hasClass('displayHiddenMenu')) {
            $('.MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
        }
    });

    //Add a cursor the the pointer
    $(".item:contains(Categories)").css("cursor", "pointer");

});
```

Here is the latest fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tig7r/htLny8a7/1/

Answer (score 2):

He's a better workaround the issue. I have listen to `clicks` `mouseevents` and `touchevents`. Therefor hopefully should work on any device. However I didn't test this on Edge. Hope it helps.

You may also listen to all `.NavMenu .item` elements and hide the `.MegaMenuDiv` if it's not Categories item, because someone might accidentally hover the categories item.

```js
// main menu
$(".item:contains(Categories)").on('mouseenter touchstart click', function(e) {
 
 // toggle MegaMenuDiv on click
 e.type == 'click' ? $('.MegaMenuDiv').toggleClass("displayHiddenMenu") : $('.MegaMenuDiv').addClass("displayHiddenMenu");
});

$('#MegaMenuDiv').on('click', function(e){
 if(e.target == $('#MegaMenuDiv').get(0)){
   $('.MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren').next().removeClass('displayHiddenMenu');
  }
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('#MegaMenuDiv .secondary-items').removeClass('displayHiddenMenu');
 $('#MegaMenuDiv').removeClass("displayHiddenMenu");
});

// MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren
$(".MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren").on('mouseenter touchstart click', function() {
 // toggle MegaMenuDiv
  $('.MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren').next().removeClass('displayHiddenMenu');
  $(this).next().addClass('displayHiddenMenu');
});
```

```css
.NavMenu{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white !important;
}

.NavMenu ul li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}

.ul_menu li a:link{
  color:white;
}

.ul_menu li a:hover{
  color:black;
}

#MegaMenuDiv{
  background:black;
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  width:550px;
  display:none;
  min-height:300px;
}

.MegaMenuDiv a:link{
  color:white;
}

.displayHiddenMenu{
  display: block !important;
}

.main-category-list li{
  list-style:none;
}

.secondary-items{
  background: #31383e;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
  width: calc(80vw - 50%);
  height: auto;
  list-style: none;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  display: none;
  height: 92%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-width: 840px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.secondary-items a:link, .secondary-items a:visited{
  color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="NavMenu">
    <ul class="ul_menu">
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <span>
                    Home
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a>
                <span>
                    Categories
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="subLevel MegaMenuDiv" id="MegaMenuDiv">
    <div class="custom_megamenu_wrapper">
        <ul class="main-category-list has-children">
            <li>
                <a class="Parent_Mega_Menu_Categories MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren" href="javascript:void(0)" style="">
                    Accessories
                </a>
                <ul class="secondary-items">
                    <li>
                        <a class="MegaMenu_Child_Link" href="https://www.google.com" style="">
                            Accessory Holders
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="MegaMenu_Child_Link" href="https://www.google.com" style="">
                            Whiteboard Starter Pack
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="Parent_Mega_Menu_Categories MegaMenuLinkMainWithChildren" href="javascript:void(0)" style="">
                    Other
                </a>
                <ul class="secondary-items">
                    <li>
                        <a class="MegaMenu_Child_Link" href="https://www.google.com" style="">
                            Accessory
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="MegaMenu_Child_Link" href="https://www.google.com" style="">
                            Starter Pack
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner code, I just found that Mouseleave causes the Sub-Menu to close right after when you tap the categories menu item on touch devices with Edge.