# Javascript, detect touch devices

Tags: javascript, touch

I'm using this function to detect if the device is a touch device:

```
function is_touch_device()
{
    return !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window);
};
```

Got this function from here: [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)

But since Chrome 25 (25.0.1364) it returns true on my desktop which isn't a touch device. 
Also I've updated IE9 to IE10 and it returns true in IE!

Searched around but couldn't find anything useful to fix this except using a something like this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

What do you recommend?

I'm looking forward to your responses!

Answer (score 4):

The code works just fine, the browser is able to understand touch events, just because your screen isn't touchable doesn't mean that the browser doesn't support the functionality. What you are looking to test is a hardware capability which isn't really testable. You can always use different ways though of seeing if the user is actual using a touch interface after touching it once, such as [this](http://alastairc.ac/2010/03/detecting-touch-based-browsing/) article describes, or many others that larger libraries use such as Modernizer.

As a reference the code actually used in the article above is:

```
function isTouchDevice() {
   var el = document.createElement('div');
   el.setAttribute('ongesturestart', 'return;');
   if(typeof el.ongesturestart == "function"){
      return true;
   }else {
      return false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
function isTouchEnabled() { return !!document.createTouch; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works on almost everything (FF,IE,Android) excepts Chrome on my Windows desktop.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect touch capability.

This question is very similar to [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript) and should perhaps be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Modernizr is not detecting touch devices. It only recognise touch browsers

Answer (score 3):

i was experiencing a false positive IE10 touch issue as well when I was visiting the site i've been working on from my laptop.  The original `is_touch_device` method, i used basically the same thing.  I modified the latter half of that statement to be the following:

```
function is_touch_device()
{
    return !!('ontouchstart' in window) || (!!('onmsgesturechange' in window) && !!window.navigator.maxTouchPoints);
}
```

`window.navigator.maxTouchPoints` seems to be something specific in IE10 based on this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772144(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [51dergees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi) for detection on the server appropriately changing page view. It has HasTouchScreen, IsSmartPhone, IsTablet properties etc.

Comment: Thanks but I'm searching for touch screen detection, not device detection

Comment: also to note, doing server-side device detection doesn't really work if you have a cdn caching your site.