# Is there a way to disable a Jquery plugin from working specifically on smartphones and tablets?

Tags: android, jquery, wordpress, tablet

Hi I've got a Jquery hover-to-play plug in that works fine on desktop but screws up the images on tablet and phone. Is there a code I can use to disable the plugin when viewed on specific pixel widths? Or another plug in that can isolate an unwanted plug in?

Thanks.

Jason

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load jQuery script in desktop browser, but not mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732847/load-jquery-script-in-desktop-browser-but-not-mobile)

Comment: Thanks for the reply null, that thread doesn't really help me though.