# Load external JS only on desktops and not on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm using an external JS plugin that loads very slowly on mobile devices and want to load it only on desktop.

My JS code is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53a4066858ab24f0"></script>
```

I read the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732847/load-jquery-script-in-desktop-browser-but-not-mobile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser) but I can't figure out how I can do this for an external JS file. Any ideas how to do this?

I tried this but this removed it from the desktop version as well, despite loading the script (monitored using Network resources in Chrome Dev Tools).

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
            url = '//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53a4066858ab24f0';
            $.getScript(url);
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: The answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732847/load-jquery-script-in-desktop-browser-but-not-mobile
By am_ doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: @EphiGabay I edited my question with the answer that I tried.

Comment: Define “desktop”. Does [the Acer Aspire Switch 10](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/series/aspireswitch10) count? How about [the Microsoft Surface Pro 3](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-gb/products/surface-pro-3)? If not, why not?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'm not that nitpicky over what qualifies as a "desktop". It's a social share plugin that wouldn't really affect the functionality of a website, if missing. As long as it is removed from most mobile devices, my question is solved.

Comment: @YinYang: good stuff, but that doesn’t remove the need to define what a “mobile device” is.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite For my purpose, device width less than `768px`?

Comment: @YinYang: maybe. Is it the device’s small screen size that’s causing the JavaScript library to load slowly?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Could be. But the irritating part is that it loads the entire script but still doesn't work as it isn't compatible with mobile devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60087/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-yin-yang).

Comment: If there’s something the script is incompatible with, then that could be something concrete you can detect before deciding whether to use the library. What’s the compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that something like this would work for you:

```
<script>
var isDesktop = (function() {
  return !('ontouchstart' in window) || !('onmsgesturechange' in window);
})();
window.isDesktop = isDesktop;
if( isDesktop ){ url = '//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53a4066858ab24f0';
                 $.getScript(url);  
               }
</script>
```

Found here: [Load jQuery script in desktop browser, but not mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732847/load-jquery-script-in-desktop-browser-but-not-mobile)
By Travis J

Comment: That didn't work. It removes it from the desktop version as well, despite loading the script.

Comment: @YinYang: it’s almost as if you and Patrick haven’t agreed what “desktop” means.