# iOS click is activating parent anchor of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

Iv run out of solutions that I can think of or find for this problem. I'm working on a fixed to the top of the page. The left side has a anchor that takes you to the top of the page, if hovered over it will show other external links. The right side is a list of page sections with anchors to scroll you to them.

this all works fine on desktop as hover and click are separate events, but on an ipad they are they same. On an iPad you should be able to touch the "Product List" list item and have the drop down menu appear. If touched again it will take you back to the top. Right now when you touch it will take you back to the top and display the hover.

Here is a jsfiddle recreating the code and issue. http://jsfiddle.net/hyaTV/5/

HTML

```
<ul class="one">
<li><a class="intrapage" href="#stage">Product Title</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="other product">other product</a></li> <!-- link that goes to different page -->
        <li><a href="other product">other product</a></li> <!-- link that goes to different page -->
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="two">
    <li><a class="intrapage" href="#section_one">birds</a></li> <!-- goes to Birds section -->
    <li><a class="intrapage" href="#section_two">bees</a></li> <!-- goes to bees section -->
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.one{float:left;list-style:none;}
ul.one ul{display:none;}
ul.one > li:hover ul{display:block;}

/* styling for right side nav */
ul.two{float:right;list-style:none;}
ul.two li{display:inline-block;}
```

JS

```
// scrolls window to element id with easing
$(".intrapage").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 850);
return false;
});
```

Comment: http://www.theverge.com seems to have solved the problem but I'm not happy with how complex their code is for the navigation, just doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [iOS :hover issue](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/) to your advantage. I believe by changing your CSS to

```
ul.one > li ul { display: none; }
ul.one > li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

That said, above *problem* doesn't exist on other mobile OS. there're no way to *mouse out* on iOS.

It's better to [detect if user is on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript) and add `.mobile` with javascript to `<body>` then toggle the sub-menu on *click* events.

CSS

`ul.one > li:hover ul, ul.one > li.hover ul { display: block; }`

JS

```
$('body.mobile ul.one > li').click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: in your css, won't the li:hover override the li.hover on ipad as it will will apply :hover after a touch event has ended?

Comment: you're right,.. it was supposed to be `body.mobile ul.one > li.hover ul {` stupid cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution which appears to work. It will require your page to include the Modernizr JS to check if touch is supported or not.

JS

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);
}

if($('html').hasClass('touch')){

    $('.one > li').click(function(e){
        if($(this).hasClass('hover')){
    //      $(this).removeClass('hover');
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        }
    });

    $('html').bind('touchstart', function(){
        if($('.one > li').is(':hover')){
                    // do nothing
        } else {
            $('.one > li.hover').removeClass('hover');
        }
    });

    $('.one a.intrapage').click(function(event){
        if($('.one > li').hasClass('hover')){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 850);
            return false;               
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $(".two .intrapage").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 850);
        return false;
    }); 

} else {
    $(".intrapage").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - 50}, 850);
        return false;
    }); 
}
```