# Detecting a physical keyboard from the browser

Tags: javascript, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I'm creating a web page which will only be of use to users with a physical keyboard.  It makes no sense to use it if you have an on-screen keyboard.  (Think typing-tutor type webapp.)

Is there any way to detect that a physical keyboard is present, from Javascript?

If not, what is the most reliable way to detect that the browser is running on a tablet or phone, rather than a desktop/laptop?

Comment: You can do it in opposite way, can we detect an touch screen instead of a physical keyboard by doing `ontouchstart`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect hardware keyboard presence with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880236/how-do-i-detect-hardware-keyboard-presence-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it's a pity that the page can't apologise to on-screen-keyboard users until they press a key.  (The `ontouchstart` would catch touchscreen laptops.)