# Styled <input type="range"> made to redirect not working on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make a slider, which on reaching a specific value, redirects to another url. The code is http://jsfiddle.net/9vs2n/

HTML:-

```
<div id="slide-wrap">
<div id="over">
    <div id="overin"></div>
</div>
<input type="range" id="in" class="slideToUnlock" value="0" max="100">
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
body {
color:white;
background: #323232;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#over {
width:80%;
border:solid thick rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
height:55px;
display:block;
position:relative;
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
border-bottom-left-radius:1em;
border-top-right-radius:1em;
}
#overin {
appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
background:#60a917;
width:75px;
height:55px;
display:block;
border-bottom-left-radius:1em;
border-top-right-radius:1em;
}
#in {
outline:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
width:80%;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:-55px;
padding:0;
height:55px;
display:block;
position:relative;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#overin:before {
color: white;
position:relative;
right:10px;
top: -10px;
width:99%;
font-size: 56px;
font-weight: bold;
content:">";
display:inline-block;
text-align:end;
}
#in::-webkit-slider-thumb {
cursor:pointer;
appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
width:75px;
height:55px;
display:block;
}
#over:before {
content:"slide to continue";
color: white;
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 10px;
z-index: -1;
font-size: 32px;
}
#slide-wrap {
margin:10px auto;
}
```

JavaScript:-

```
document.getElementById('in').onmouseup = function () {
var val = document.getElementById('in').value;
if (val >= 50) {

    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
} else {
    this.value = 0;
    zero()
}
}

document.getElementById('in').onmousemove = function () {
enlarge();
}

function enlarge() {
if (document.getElementById('in').value > 10) {
    document.getElementById('overin').style.width = document.getElementById('in').value + "%";
}
}

function zero() {
document.getElementById('overin').style.width = '80px';
}

setInterval(loop1(), 1);

function loop1() {
document.getElementById('over').style.width = document.getElementById('in').style.width;
}
```

It works properly, but the problem is that it's not working on touch devices, i've tried it on ipad, please try and try to solve this. The page is available at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99185097/donotdelete/index.html

Comment: Guys, instead of negatively rating, please answer.

Comment: I was going to say that it works for me, then I saw your last comment! I don't have much touch interface experience right now, so I hope someone helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. You'll have to add some touch events to this. `onmouseup` & `onmousestart` will trigger only mouse events and from what I've seen, doesnt work on touch screens. The events you have to add are `touchmove` & `touchend` as well. [Here's a reference link from MDN for touch events of HTML5.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent)

This is how your code needs to be structured :

```
var el = document.getElementById('in');

//mouse events
//gave names to the functions bound this, since w'll be using them two times. 
el.onmousemove = enlarge;
el.onmouseup = redirect;


//touch events 
//check if device has touch screen 
// CREDIT : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886/1217785
if (is_touch_device()) {
    console.log(true);
    //onmousemove = touchmove
    el.addEventListener("touchmove", enlarge, false)
    //onmouseup = touchend
    el.addEventListener("touchend", redirect, false)
}

//this function checks whether the device is a touch screen or not, else no binding will be done.
function is_touch_device() {
    var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window ||
        'onmsgesturechange' in window;
    
    console.log(isTouch);
    return isTouch;
};

//the rest of your functions

function redirect() {
    var val = document.getElementById('in').value;
    if (val >= 50) {

        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
    } else {
        this.value = 0;
        zero()
    }
}


function enlarge() {
    if (document.getElementById('in').value > 10) {
        document.getElementById('overin').style.width = document.getElementById('in').value + "%";
    }
}

//other code
```

And here's the updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/9vs2n/6/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I've tried your fiddle on iPad, it doesn't redirect. Can you please instead give me a solution which onLoad checks whether the device is touch, and changes it to a clickable button. I don't have much touch javascript experience.

Comment: Will this be able to check whether the device is a touch device before the user actually touches the screen, because i think that i'm going to make it change the input's type from range to button, and make it intercept a click to continue, if onLoad it finds that the device is touch. If not then please give me a code for that. Your current answer is very buggy.

Comment: what "bugs" do u find in this? I'm testing this on an iPad right now and it works for me.

Comment: and yes all you have to do is move that `if` condition to `window.onload` property. Pretty much that.

Comment: I tried it on ipad in vertical orientation and it worked, but not in horizontal orientation.

Comment: But still, no problem if it doesnt work in horizontal mode. Thanks man!

Comment: Please amrk this as the right answer if you think this has helped you. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Yeah, thanx, hungerpain!!