# How to style for only non-touch devices in css?

Tags: html, css, modernizr, mousehover

I am creating a hover effect for buttons in pure CSS. But I want this effect to happen only when mouse hover occurs. But the hover effect is occurring when touch event occurs on button in touch devices. How can I limit this effect for only non-touch devices?

```
.toolbar-button:not(.media-control):not(#page-count-button):hover:enabled:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 37px;
    height: 34px;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255, 0)), color-stop(0.65, rgba(255,255,255, 0.1)), to(rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
}
```

Note: I'm using jQuery-touch-punch in this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think your are making use of modernizr. Then its quit easy

just add class ".no-js"

```
 .no-touch a:hover,
 .no-js a:hover { color: #06e; }
```

check this link for further explanation [Github- No :hover](https://gist.github.com/vasilisvg/1275792)

Comment: Related answer how to detect touch device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886/2453148

Answer (score 0):

What if you -- used media queries and did one of these?

```
@media (max-width:500px) and (min-width:320px) { /* some specific mobile viewport */

    .toolbar-button:desktopbuttonstyles {
        display: none;
    }

    .toolbar-button:MOBILEbuttonstyles {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but it should work.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:1024px) /*catch touch screen devices */
{

    .toolbar-button:not(.media-control):not(#page-count-button):hover:enabled:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 37px;
        height: 34px;
        background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255, 0)), color-stop(0.65, rgba(255,255,255, 0.1)), to(rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)));
        background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
        background-image: linear-gradient( rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, 0.15) 70%, rgba(255,255,255, 0.6));
    }

    }
```

You can also use modernizer and:

```
.touch *:hover {
    place default values here
}
```