# CSS media query to detect device type regardless of size

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, usability

I have been looking into media queries, but so far all the examples I can find on google and Stack Overflow have been to use specific sizes (`max-width`, `max-device-width`, etc.) The problem with this is that it doesn't give me the flexibility I need. I want to be able to deliver a ** specifically tailored** experience to desktops and tablets.

The reason I want to do this is that interacting with a tablet is different than interacting with a small computer monitor. An iPad in landscape orientation is 1024x768, which also happens to be a common computer monitor size. The difference however is that on a computer, pointing to small controls with a mouse is easy, but it is very difficult to tap the same size controls on an iPad, especially for someone with large or clumsy fingers.

How can I deliver a tailored experience to an iPad user vs a desktop user with a monitor of the same size? I'd like the desktop experience to not be forced to use jumbo sized buttons that a touch experience requires.

Is this possible with media queries, or something else? I see that there's a "handheld" option for media queries, but I've read that most small device browsers ignore this.

Comment: You can go the old school route and detect OS and all that jazz with htaccess and force them to a subdomain. Otherwise just figure it's not a huge deal for people with tablet sized monitors to get a tablet view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with media queries. There is a "handheld" media type, but most, if not all modern handheld devices identify themselves as "screen".

To do it with javascript, see this question:
[What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)

Comment: Note that a phone can use a mouse and a computer can have a touchscreen; so it might not be a good idea to say "whatever has a touchscreen is a mobile" or wise versa.

Comment: Not a problem @YektaDev. The answers in that link uses ontouchstart.