# Writing media queries for mobile devices, low-res desktop and hi-res desktop

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm using both the screen width and screen height to detect the difference between mobile and desktops and then detect high resolution desktops vs. low resolution desktops.

I have some JavaScript that I use to load different CSS files. It looks like this:

**JavaScript**

```js
<script>
  if (screen.width > 800) { 

    if (screen.height < 900) { 
      document.write('<link href="/LowRes.css" type="text/css" />'); 
    } else { 
      document.write('<link href="/HiRes.css" type="text/css" />'); 
    }

} else {

    document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">');
    document.write('<link href="/Mobile.css" type="text/css" />'); 
}
</script>
```

I want to change that and use media queries, and this is what I have:

**CSS**

```
<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 801px) and (min-device-width: 801px)" href="low.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="screen and (min-device-height: 901px)" href="hi.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="screen and (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation : portrait), screen and (max-device-height: 800px) and (orientation : landscape)" href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This allows for the mobile stylesheet to be downloaded regardless of the orientation. However, the desktop stylesheet is always set to hi-res even if it's actually low-res.

[image]

As you can see, I've got the desktop mode on height 800px, the media query is set for `min-device-height:901px` and yet it's downloading the hi-res stylesheet. Why is that?

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to explain?

Comment: You understand that you need media queries here, but you didn't think to maybe look into how one would go about *writing* media queries?

Comment: @cimmanon: this is not a duplicate! I've updated my question and the answers in the question you've pointed to have nothing to do with the question. I'm looking for 3 rules to replicate the javascript; I've updated the question. As the picture shows, I'm stuck on why the min-device-height:901px that should restrict the stylesheet to desktop low res is not working. The question is "how to write 3 rules to detect mobile/desktop low res/desktop hi res" and so far all the answers have lots of rules but not one answer has the problem reduced down to just 3 rules. So no, this is not a duplicate IMHO

Comment: Unless you physically changed the resolution of your device, all you're doing is changing the size of the viewport, and the *device-width properties do not respond to viewport changes.  If you wanted what you were asking for, you would have taken the advice in the question this was marked as a duplicate of rather than stomping your feet and declaring "this isn't a duplicate, it didn't give me the exact code I needed to copy/paste into my project!"

Comment: @cimmanon: well anyway, detecting mobile/low-res desktop/hi-res desktop in 3 media queries is what this question's about. For now I have it working in javascript and I'm looking to replace it. Can you revert the duplicate to see what others can come up with?

Comment: device-width is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Include all CSS files to your `<head>`. Alternatively, you can combine them to a single CSS file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link href="/Mobile.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="/LowRes.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="/HiRes.css" type="text/css" />
```

Then you change the files by wrapping their contents to media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) { 
    // all contents of Mobile.css
}
@media (min-width: 801px) and (max-height:900px) { 
    // all contents of LowRes.css
}
@media (min-width: 801px) and (min-height:901px) { 
    // all contents of HiRes.css
}
```

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for CSS media queries. As an alternative you could use [nested media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css) but some old browsers might not support them.

Comment: That doesn't work because if a user is on a mobile and rotates to landscape then he's not on mobile anymore.

Comment: I see. Using only media queries you cannot detect the device type. You will still need to rely on JavaScript to make this distinction (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085063)). Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029) might be helpful.

Comment: Ok, could you vote to reopen the question??

Comment: Sure thing. R u still looking for a CSS-only solution?

Comment: Yes, my goal is to replace the javascript with a pure CSS media query implementation.