# Apply styles only in landscape and only on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I am using `@media (orientation:landscape){..}` media type to apply styles only in landscape mode and it should apply only in Mobile Devices below `767px`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media query to detect device type regardless of size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085063/css-media-query-to-detect-device-type-regardless-of-size)

Answer (score 3):

```
@media (orientation:landscape) and (max-width: 767px){..}
```

For detecting device type, you can use javascript:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  // your code which add styles
}
```

Comment: It should only work in Mobile Devices but that media type will work in both desktop and Mobile Device, I need it should only apply my styles in mobile device, I mean if i resize my browser into below 767px it should not work in the browser.

Comment: Then you should take a look on that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085063/css-media-query-to-detect-device-type-regardless-of-size

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding ;)

Comment: I found one solution its working for me **max-device-width**  it is working only in mobile devices, its not working in browser in resize mode.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't think of it. Just make sure it's properly supported, I cannot find it on www.caniuse.com :).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to identify the mobile devices by your given width, than you can use [`max-width` in your media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) as well:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  ...
}
```

Furthermore there is a [nice article on CSS-Tricks](http://@media%20(orientation:landscape)%20and%20(max-width:%20767px)%7B..%7D) about how to apply the styles to different devices with media queries.

You can also use `handheld` type in your media query, but unfortunately that's not supported by most of the modern mobile devices (they identify themselves as `screen`).

To really detect if a device is mobile, you need to use Javascript.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803838/detecting-if-a-device-is-able-to-change-orientation-in-javascript/13805337#13805337) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript).

Comment: Actually it should not work in browser if i resize my browser in to 767px , It will work as per my requirement ?