# Get touch movement within jqPlot canvas to enable cursor highlighting

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, touch, jqplot

Can we enable touch support for the jqPlot crosshair cursor from "jqplot.cursor.js"?

An example is here:
http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html

My goal is to enable the crosshair for touch devices.

Possible workaround:
Using html5 touch events to get the finger position?

Comment: By touch support - do you mean dragging? The crosshair is merely the appearance of the cursor when you hover over the graph, which is clearly not possible since there is no cursor on a touch display.

Comment: Yes, I meant dragging. For example, I need to enable zooming into the plot on a touch device.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing is working in touch enabled device is `tool-tip on tapping` the point plotted on graph.
`jqplot` has not any `plug-in` for `zooming in touch enabled device`.

The thing you can do is check [if device is touch enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript#answer-4819886) ?
Set limit while device is touch enabled and display simple graph with latest values only.

Comment: Pardon, I got dragging to work when using the plugin jqplot.mobile.js

Comment: Since you were comitted to help. bounty is yours!

Comment: I was recently going through the same issue, so this is what i found.