# Why is 'ontouchstart' in window "supported by most browsers"?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm in the process of refactoring some code that someone else wrote. There is function that uses:

```
!!('ontouchstart' in window)
```

I've seen this used in other projects: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/touchevents.js#L40
And in a Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886/1127635

But it seems like it could be slower than alternatives: http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in-vs-undefined/12

So why use this possibly slower alternative? What browsers don't support other solutions?

Comment: I don't really understand the main question of your post. Do you want to know why `x in y` approach is used or if it is enough to check for `ontouchstart` property in `window` object?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The question is: why is it used instead of other available options?

Comment: Hm... Obviously to check if the browser supports touch event, which is essential in devices with touch screens. `x in y` is used just for better readability I guess.

Comment: Apparently not. `x in y` seems to be used for cross browser compatibility. And it seems like it could be slower than alternatives: http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in-vs-undefined/12

Comment: Typically this would only be called once per page load, so I'd guess that speed isn't a concern for most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your alternative tests are flawed in some way:

- `window.ontouchstart !== null` tests for a non-`null` listener. Testing the value of `ontouchstart` is a risky approach because libraries or other code might change the value of `ontouchstart`. Testing the value is a bad approach; it would be much better to test for the existence of the property itself, which brings us to your next proposed test...
- `window.hasOwnProperty('ontouchstart')` tests if the `window` object has its own `ontouchstart` property. In some browsers (I've just confirmed this on Chrome 37 and IE9), `window` *doesn't* have its own `on`-event properties; instead, they are properties of `window.__proto__`.

We shouldn't test for a value (because previous code may have changed the value before we run our code) and we can't test for `window`'s own property, because browser differ in their implementation of where event listener properties exist in `window`'s prototype chain. So, our most consistent option is to test whether the property exists (regardless of value) anywhere in `window`'s prototype chain. This is exactly what we do with the `in` operator.

Of course, if someone else's code runs before our test, they could add an `ontouchstart` property where there originally wasn't one. Testing support for events with absolute rigor simply isn't possible and it's an awful business.

Comment: How about `window.ontouchstart !== void 0`?

Comment: Yes, but possibly cross browser and faster. Would that be cross browser?

Comment: Are you really that concerned about speed? How many times per second are you testing whether the browser supports touch events? Human readability of code is vastly more important here. As for whether it would work consistently: maybe. It depends whether all browsers forbid setting `on`-event properties to `undefined` (which would cause `!=== void 0` to fail if it happened).

Comment: No, I am not. I'm just curious. How it `window.ontouchstart !== undefined` less readable than `ontouchstart in window`? Also, if this allows to remove the `DocumentTouch` test that modernizr uses, that would be valuable. Do you know of browsers that disallow setting `on`-event properties to `undefined`?

Comment: @conradk That's fair; I'll concede that `=== undefined` is perfectly readable (although `void 0` is *extremely* unclear as a virtually unused language feature; please don't do that). I'm much less quick to assume that `on`-properties can not be set to `undefined` in all browsers (which, again, would mess up your test if some other code got in first). Additionally, I'm not even sure if older browsers consistently initialize `on`-properties to `null`. Maybe they do, but I don't have the browsers to test on.