# How to stop the :hover state from being active on a touchscreen?

Tags: css, hover, touch

On my site http://www.robertfikesiv.com/ when you touch an element with a :hover event, the :hover properties will stay active until another element is touched that has a :hover property. The only way to remove the properties from being active is to refresh the page.

How do I disable the :hover event for ony touch screen devices?

Comment: find if the device is touch screen using mordernizr and then add a class based on it and maybe override your :hover properties. just a thought  refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the html element that identifies a non touch device, and on the first 'touchstart' event remove that class. The below code is a rudimentary example, but it should work none the less.

HTML

```
<html class="notouch">...
```

CSS

```
.notouch .clickable:hover{
   color: #f00;
}
```

JS

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
    var className = document.querySelector('html').className;
    document.querySelector('html').className = className.replace(/notouch/, '');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into a handy new thing called pointer-events.  If you put pointer-events: none on an element then hover and click events will be disabled, even in JS.