# How to write if not (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, if-statement, user-agent, detect

You can detect if the visitor uses a mobile device:

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                // here my codes }
```

But how to turn this code into an if not (to get all devices that are not these ones)?

Maybe something like this?

```
if !(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                // here my codes }
```

As you understand my question goes about standard syntax (I am learning).

Comment: FYI, this is JavaScript, not jQuery. jQuery is a DOM manipulation framework that is implemented in the language of JavaScript.

Comment: can always use `===false` ... or wrap the whole thing inside `()` and do `if(!(/Andr......i.test(navigator.userAgent)))`

Comment: yes @charlietfl, looks what I am searching for. If I write your solution as whole code would it be like this? `if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                // here my codes }`
Maybe you can place your entire code as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a variable might be best for readability

```
var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if(!isMobile){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement with an else. The else will trigger if the condition in your if statement is not met.

```
if(/Android | webOS | iPhone| iPad| iPod| BlackBerry| BB| PlayBook| IEMobile| Windows Phone| Kindle| Silk| Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

  //code 

}else{

  //other code

}
```

Comment: Because my question was only about "if not", does this mean I have to place my code inside the else { }, and I can leave the codes inside if { } blank?

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. You shouldn't use an if/else with a blank if. It would be better to use charlietfl's answer. Using the ! inside the if brackets is the correct method. Just an fyi though, if you're trying to detect mobile devices, you may be better off checking for a touch event (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886/6015622). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @kravse for the useful suggestion.