# Should I consider every mobile smaller than 768px a touch device?

Tags: html, css, browser, opera, user-agent

I have been making a website which behaves differently on touch device than desktop. The main difference is that most of the hover effects are changed to clicks on touch devices. To check if user agent is a touch device I use this in javascript:

```
var yesIfTouchDevice = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));

if(istouchdevice) {
  // change hover to clicks
}
```

Then in css I assumed that every user agent below 768px would be a touch device. I made the layout presuming that. E.g. I have a toggle button that shows menu on tap. Further I have many other things that show pop up and other hidden layer only on tap(touch event).

Just a few minutes ago the thought occured that there are many mobiles that are not touch enabled, like Nokia Asha and N series and many more which I don't even know. My question is:

1. What is the market share of non touch mobile browsers?  How many percent users use those browsers?
2. I have made my whole website with bootstrap assuming touch functionality for small screen devices. Does modern day html css best practices suggest making website only for touch enabled mobile devices?

**Edit:** Upon listening to the suggestions I have decided to optimize for non-touch mobile devices too. But I am not sure how they mimic mouse behavior in general. I am guessing that elements that are focusable can be selected and clicked. So,

3. Should I make all my elements that work on hover, e.g. the navigation, focusable with `tabindex = "1"`?

I have been testing my site on opera mini browser in Kemulator and found that it reloads page when I click on navigation and some other layers are not shown, e.g. the bootstrap modal pop up.

4. Does opera mini browser not support javascript well?

Comment: Why not just use js/jQuery plugins to map touch events to mouse events and do not over-complicate code?

Comment: This might suit the ux exchange better: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

I will however say that there are very few browsers that still use < 800px. That said, you should design your site to work with touch and mouse at all resolutions and screen sizes. what is it you are trying to do that needs to determine touch/mouse?

Comment: @arlyon What you mean `there are very few browsers that still use < 800px`? You can always resize your browser to fit only portion of screen. Why everyone thinks that you always use browser in maximized mode?

Comment: @Justinas I could not understand your point. Would non touch mobile devices have some sort of mouse cursor functionality? And which jquery plugin does that?

Comment: Also if the question is more appropriate over user experience stack exchange then Please mod migrate the question over there.

Comment: The question was "what is the market share of non touch mobile browsers? How many percent users use those browsers?". There are very few non touch small screen mobile browsers. The only ones I can think of are PSPs and DS. I didn't specify I was talking about non touch.

Then to answer the second part I said that you should design your site to be used for mouse and touch no matter the resolution for exactly the reason you provided. People resize browsers all the time.

Comment: @arlyon Can there be data about how many users view website in desktop browser by resizing below 786? Actually the problem is some layout on hover below 768 in my site will break.

Comment: The main problem with the question is that there is no direct link between screen size and touch-enabled. There are very large screens that are touch devices. So it's not a good idea to assume a touch device from screen size. That is all.

Comment: @MrLister I have taken care of tablets > 768. I show desktop like layout and by checking touch enable I convert hover events to click where required. My only concern is should I also optimize for <786 non-touch devices?

Comment: No you should never consider a device as touch based on window size, it's a [Post hoc ergo propter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc). Have said that, the question is duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo I am not asking for how to check if device is touch enabled.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. What is the market share of non touch mobile browsers? How many percent users use those browsers?

We don't have this data. But based on current market share of OS and devices user share, it hardly reach 1%. But the main concern is not because of non-touch mobile devices. Browser windows are not always maximized, user can decrease thei width even < 768px. ie. Use side-by-side browser and a notepad on a 1400 x 900 resolution.

> 2. I have made my whole website with bootstrap assuming touch functionality for small screen devices. Does modern day html css best practices suggest making website only for touch enabled mobile devices?

No. Current suggestion is responsive design using mobile-first approach.
Using mobile website apart duplicates code, design, maintenance and expenses. It also affects SEO and traffic analyses for business purpose.

> Should I make all my elements that work on hover, e.g. the navigation, focusable with tabindex = "1"?

Yes and no. All clickable elements (buttons, links) and input form should be object of accessible navigation, but you do not necessarily need to set `tabindex` for all clickable elements to make then "focusable" element, the browser will do it as default ordering by appearance in code. Use `tabindex` to enforce your navigation links flow, if default order doesn't make sense to you or if you want to make sure you will have corrected flow.

> 4. I have been testing my site on opera mini browser in Kemulator and found that it reloads page when I click on navigation and some other layers are not shown, e.g. the bootstrap modal pop up.
>
> Does opera mini browser not support javascript well?

No. As well as modern CSS. Opera Mini reduces interactivity due to its nature of using a proxy to compress page resources.

Opera Mini is more popular in Africa, Middle East and Eastern Europe.
If these region are not your user focus, I would *suggest* you to not spent time on make website fully work on Opera Mini.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Would `tabindex = "1"` for every clickable element make them clickable(focusable?) on non touch browsers like default Nokia mobile browsers?

Comment: That I can't answer you for sure, but I've updated my answer on this topic

Answer (score 1):

> What is the market share of non touch mobile browsers? How many percent users use those browsers?

This is generally region dependent so it depends on your audience. You can get some idea from

https://deviceatlas.com/device-data/explorer/webusage-by-country/traffic/mobile/country/us/type/browser_name

http://gs.statcounter.com/#all-as-ww-monthly-201610-201612-map

But in my experience these are not very helpful because a lot is determined the type of customer your product focusses unless it is a very widely adapted product on e.g. On an niche e-commerce site selling high value stuff you will find Safari prominent. So before solving the problem if you can collect some data (if you have existing product) or ask in forums/fb groups to people who have a product in a similar domain, it will help you in prioritizing, because building is a smaller issue than maintaining it.

> I have made my whole website with bootstrap assuming touch functionality for small screen devices. Does modern day html css best practices suggest making website only for touch enabled mobile devices?
>   Edit: Upon listening to the suggestions I have decided to optimize for non-touch mobile devices too. But I am not sure how they mimic mouse behavior in general. I am guessing that elements that are focusable can be selected and clicked. So,

If you want to cover wide range of browsers use https://modernizr.com to detect features and respond accordingly or have fallback interactions. Caution, it's always not a good idea to pull a library if you want only few features, so see your use cases. On the other hand the advantage is it keeps getting updated.

You can see the list of touch (and similar) events fired by different browsers here http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html#link1

For list of apple non-touch events take check this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Force_Touch_events

Similarly you will have to dig for event lists for browsers which you want to support.

> Should I make all my elements that work on hover, e.g. the navigation, focusable with tabindex = "1"?

For tabindex what Andre suggested is right (have the right order for important elements, which should be done at testing stage).

Check this to get an understanding when to avoid and cases where it can create an issue. There are more than the ones listed here, so do a good research if you are playing too much with tabindex.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex

I have been testing my site on opera mini browser in Kemulator and found that it reloads page when I click on navigation and some other layers are not shown, e.g. the bootstrap modal pop up.

> Does opera mini browser not support javascript well?

In most cases Opera Mini processing is done via Opera servers, which often prevents JS from working correctly.

These are the workarounds for some features, for which you can refer to https://operamini.tips/#/

All being said, still I would suggest, do a good target user research, and from there prioritize your list of support for your initial versions. It may require investment of time and maybe some money too but it is totally worth it. Then improve on the shortlisted ones till you are able to remove major bugs, and when you have bandwidth then attack the next part of the list. Having an approach of supporting too many browsers/devices/screens at first will take you down the "support labyrinth" from where you will be stuck with removing bugs everywhere, and feature development will go out of focus.

Also integrate GA analytics (or any other) well and attach events to major interactions, and keep monitoring according to screen sizes, device and browsers. e.g. Opera Mini gives me 0 events in some pages and that raises an alarm. Sometimes it may not be 0 but a low ratio of users who interacted /users visited. You can attach events with scroll, field select etc. Prioritize first on major features of your product, track, choose what to focus on, improve, test and then move to next part. So basically this will form a matrix of features with browsers/screen sizes and then prioritize accordingly depending on your traffic type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code from detectmobilebrowsers. Just replace the url `http://www.detectmobilebrowsers.com/mobile` with the url for the mobile webpage. This is a direct [link](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/javascript) to the javascript code. Just change the file extension to js and everything works.