# Deal with touch desvices and hover effects

Tags: jquery, css, hover, touch

I try to remove or prevent all hover effect on a touch device. I try to use several scripts, but it does not work for me. How can I  test it, with dev tools? I try such script but have some error.  Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. But it works here [codepen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/XpONLm)
There is error cause the dom tree has not loaded yet?

```
<html class="hover-active">

$(window).on('load', function() {

        if (!('addEventListener' in window)) {
            return;
        }

        var htmlElement = document.querySelector('html');

        function touchStart() {
            htmlElement.classList.remove('hover-active');

            htmlElement.removeEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
        }

        htmlElement.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
    });
```

also I try this one

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){}
```

Also I try use modernizr, it works only for each selector inside html.touch and html.no-touch

```
function is_touch_device() {
 return 'ontouchstart' in window        // works on most browsers 
  || navigator.maxTouchPoints;       // works on IE10/11 and Surface
};

if ( is_touch_device() ) {
  $('html').addClass('touch')
} else {
  $('html').addClass('no-touch')
} 


html.touch .hover-me:hover {
   pointer-events: none !important;
   cursor: pointer;

}
html.touch a:hover {
   pointer-events: none !important;
   cursor: pointer;
}

/* FOR THE DESKTOP, SET THE HOVER STATE */
html.no-touch .hover-me:hover {
   width: auto;
   color:blue;
   background:green;
}
html.no-touch a:hover {
   width: auto;
   color:blue;
   background:green;
}
```

But I need remove all :hover selector, the * does not work. Also It's not working.

```
  .hover-me:hover {
     background: yellow;
 }
html.touch .hover-me:hover {
   pointer-events: none !important;
   cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)

Comment: Are you just trying to prevent your css hover effects?

Comment: I need to remove all hover effects on the touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all hover effects on touch devices, you can use CSS Media Queries to make sure the device fully responds to hover before applying any `:hover` styles by placing them inside `@media (hover: hover)`

```
@media (hover: hover){
  .hover-me:hover {
     background: yellow;
 }
}
```