# Detect if the device has a keyboard, or is a touch device

Tags: android, jquery, ios, keyboard, swipe

What would be the best solution to detect if the user is on a device with keyboard with arrow and esc keys, or is on a mobile device with touch functionality - like swipe?

I have a image gallery which I would like to display either arrow keys if they are on a device with a keyboard.
Or, if they are on a mobile device, I would like to tell them to swipe left or right.

Here's my gallery : http://kiledesign.no/?side=Foto&vis=Galleri

I have modified the core code for the gallery plugin ([jQuery Gridder](https://github.com/oriongunning/gridder/)) so the user can use the arrow keys left/up for previous image, and right/down for next image.
I have also included esc-key to close the full view.

In addition, I have added jquery mobile swipe left (prev)/right (next).

Now I would like to find a way to determen which tips to present based on what device.

I thought about `css media query`. Like `min-width`.
But there is mini-computers with quite small screens, and there's tablet, or even phones with quite high resoultions...
So I don't think it's a fool-proof solution...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` to check if agent is computer or mobile like this:

```
var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android...etc/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (isMobile) {
  /* Set your code here */
}
```

Also may detect if device is has an touch screen or no like this:

```
function is_touch_device() {
  var prefixes = ' -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- '.split(' ');
  var mq = function(query) {
    return window.matchMedia(query).matches;
  }

  if (('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) {
    return true;
  }

  // include the 'heartz' as a way to have a non matching MQ to help terminate the join
  // https://git.io/vznFH
  var query = ['(', prefixes.join('touch-enabled),('), 'heartz', ')'].join('');
  return mq(query);
}
```

This second code answer copy from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript).